# How can I remove trailing spaces from a SQL Server 2008 query when exporting to csv?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Here's the problem.  I run a query in SQL Server Management Studio.  I click "Save results As..." and save the file as CSV.  When I open the CSV file (with Notepad or any text editor), trailing spaces have been added on every column to make them a uniform width.  This is extremely frustrating, because when I open the file with Excel, it auto-converts the fields into columns, changing account numbers and such to scientific notation.

With SQL Server 2005, there are no trailing spaces added, so Excel just puts all the data in a single column.  Then I can convert text to columns and specify every column to be Text.  But my company has switched me to SQL Server 2008 and now the only way to get the correct formatting is to import the CSV into Access, run Trim functions in Access (and thus change the field names) to get rid of the spaces, then export from Access to Excel.  PLEASE HELP!!!  Why the heck is SQL Server 2008 adding trailing spaces and where is the option to make it stop???

SOLVED: Please see my answer below.

Comment: Please note, the trailing spaces are getting added AFTER exporting to CSV.  They do NOT exist in the resultset in SQL Server.  They DO exist in the resulting CSV file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't figured out why a CSV created by SQL Server 2008 behaves differently in Excel than one created in SQL Server 2005, I have found a solution to my immediate problem.

First of all, the trailing spaces don't seem to be the problem. However, SS2008 is adding them where SS2005 does not and it is annoying. But this is not the main cause of my problem.

When right clicking the resulting CSV file then clicking Open With -> Excel, it was autoformatting into badly formatted columns (where SS2005's CSV file opens with all the data in a single column). To solve this, I just open Excel first, then open the CSV file from within Excel. This gives me the column formatting dialogue I was missing.

Answer (score 3):

You can just use ltrim and rtrim in sql to trim the results, so your resultset doesn't include the trailing spaces...

```
select ltrim(rtrim(field) as trimmedField from table
```

Comment: This doesn't help.  The spaces don't exist in my result set until AFTER I export to CSV.  The resultset in the SQL Management Studio window does not have the spaces.

Comment: but you said that you take the CSV file into access to get rid of the trailing spaces, BEFORE you export it into excel, so its not the export to excel that is putting the spaces. Can you open up the CSV file in a text editor like notepad (right AFTER you save it from sql server), and see if there are spaces in it?

Comment: Yes - if I open the text file in Notepad there are trailing spaces.  But in SQL Server I don't see the trailing spaces.  And, if I run the exact same query in SQL Server 2005, this problem doesn't happen.  There are no spaces added in the CSV file.

Comment: Okay I limited the query to a fields which areuniform in width so there are no trailing spaces.  Still Excel opens the file autoformatted into columns so the account numbers are scientific notation.  When I do the exact same process with SQL Server 2005, then open the CSV in Ecel, all the data is in a single column.  Then I can do text-to-columns to format it correctly.  The two CSV files look identical, but the one that had been created by SQL Server 2008 opens differently.  Should I repost my question without the mention of trailing spaces?

Comment: You can change the scientific notation very easily by formatting the numbers in excel. Is there a way you can put an excerpt of the data from the file? Sounds like in 2008 they improved the CSV output, so excel automaticallly recognises the tab spaces...

Comment: True it is possible to reformat the scientific notation in Excel, but in my typical adhoc queries there will be 15-20 fields that need to be fixed.  This is tedious when previously I did one simple manual action (text to columns).  No worries though, I solved it.  Please see my edits to the original post - I figured out the solution (open Excel first, then open the file from within Excel).

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the problem is that you are using **char** and **nchar** in tables schema instead of **varchar** and **nvarchar**. Changing the column types might have as consequence that the generated CSV's have no trailing spaces anymore.

Here is a link to the types difference: [What is the difference between char, nchar, varchar, and nvarchar in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server)