# How to delete leading empty space in a SQL Database Table using MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I imported an Excel sheet with countries into a database table.

Unfortunately all rows have some leading empty space.

So, how can I delete these empty spaces?

Comment: Why not clean up the data before you upload it.

Comment: Another similar question with different approach - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7322333/how-can-i-remove-trailing-spaces-from-a-sql-server-2008-query-when-exporting-to

Answer (score 41, accepted):

This will remove leading and trailing spaces

```
Update tablename set fieldName = ltrim(rtrim(fieldName));
```

some versions of SQL Support

```
Update tablename set fieldName = trim(fieldName);
```

If you just want to remove leading

```
update tablename set fieldName = LTRIM(fieldName);
```