# Can't update data in NVarChar column of a table in SSMS

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in an SSMS database:
[image: table in SSMS]

I am trying to update the contents of the "Name" column by removing the leading spaces from every entry. Following the question [How to delete leading empty space in a SQL Database Table using MS SQL Server Managment Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14501440/how-to-delete-leading-empty-space-in-a-sql-database-table-using-ms-sql-server-ma), I am therefore trying to run the following:

```
UPDATE ReferenceHierarchy set Name = LTRIM(Name)
```

The problem is that when I try to run it, it says "Name" is an invalid column. When I look at the code completion options for "Name", it sees the three fields ID, ParentID, and Sequence. Interestingly, these are the three non-NVarChar fields.

What could be the problem? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you are running against the correct database? Start the statement with `USE <database_name>;` to be sure.

Comment: BINGO, that was the key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TT's comment was the key to solving this one. I actually think there is an interesting moral here: if things are not working the way you think they should, perhaps your enviornment is not what you think it is. What was actually happening was that I had in SSMS an old version of the same database in which the ReferenceHierarchy table did not have a "name" column. And without realizing it, I was running my query against that version. Running it against the correct version of the database solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

LTRIM only removes the leading NORMAL Spaces. In your case it may be the Tab space.

Try this for TAB SPACE

```
    UPDATE ReferenceHierarchy set Name = LTRIM(REPLACE(Name,(CHAR(9)),''))
```

If your space character not a TAB Space and Normal space then it might by non Unicode character 
Then Try this

```
    UPDATE REFERENCEHIERARCHY SET NAME = TRIM(LTRIM(CASE WHEN NAME NOT LIKE '[A-ZA-Z0-9]%'
                           THEN STUFF(NAME, 1, 1, ' ')ELSE NAME END))
```