# How to remove the 1st character from a column in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a Table, Table A, and in table A I have Field A. There are values in field A like the following:

```
Street A
Street B
,Street C
Street D
etc
```

I would like to know if there is any SQL that will allow me to either remove the 1st character  from Field A where there is a ,.

I have know idea where to start I can select all the rows which have a , in Field A but I don't know where to start when trying to remove it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET    YourCol = SUBSTRING(YourCol, 2, 0+0x7fffffff) 
WHERE YourCol LIKE ',%'
```

Answer (score 13):

If you'd rather not care about the length, STUFF is the right candidate :

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET    YourCol = STUFF(YourCol, 1, 1, '')
WHERE YourCol LIKE ',%'
```

Comment: To be clear there is no particular need to care about the length with `SUBSTRING` either - it doesn' t matter if it is over specified so you can set it to max int.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the [`RIGHT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177532.aspx), [`LEN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173486.aspx) and [`RTRIM`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178660.aspx) functions

```sql
UPDATE TableA
SET FieldA = RIGHT(RTRIM(FieldA), LEN(FieldA) - 1)
WHERE FieldA LIKE ',%'
```

[Example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/6ed6b/1/0)

Comment: @MartinSmith thanks for pointing that out, I've updated it to use the the datalength function

Comment: Of course if their column datatype is `UNICODE` or they are on a double byte collation this may not be correct though.

Comment: i updated for unicode, not sure if double byte collation makes any difference to data length though

Comment: [Example of that here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server/8250586#8250586)

Comment: If you are determined to use `RIGHT` probably the easiest way would be `RIGHT(RTRIM(FieldA), LEN(FieldA) - 1)`

Comment: That seems so over the top, is there any benefit to using the `RIGHT` function instead of the `SUBSTRING` function

Answer (score 2):

You can use TSQL `SUBSTRING`  function

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Use `LEN` to get the length of the field.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190329.aspx

```
SUBSTRING(FieldA, 2, LEN(FieldA) - 1)
```