# ASP MVC: Weird white spaces on the textbox whenever i try to edit a record

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

here is what appears:

[image: White spaces?]

I used the template and i passed my model onto my view and i notice that they get those white spaces. I've been trying to default a `DropDownList` for my gender but somehow, they don't work. I was trying to debug and thought that maybe it's because of those weird white spaces. (All of them have it except department).

How do i resolve the issue?

I would also like to add that i use `Entity Framework`.

**Model**

```
[Table("carl")]
public class Employee
{


    public int id { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("First Name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "First name is required")]
    public string firstname { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Last name")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Last name is required")]
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Gender is required")]
    public string gender { get; set; }


    [DisplayName("Department")]
    [Range(1, 3)]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Dep name is required")]
    public int department { get; set; }

    public List<String> Players = new List<String> { "test", "test" };
}
```

**Controller**

```
 [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {

        EmployeeContext emp = new EmployeeContext();
        Employee sel = emp.Employees.Single(x => x.id == id);

        return View(sel);

    }
```

**View**

```
@model MvcApplication6.Models.Employee

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
@Html.ValidationSummary(true)

<fieldset>
    <legend>Employee</legend>

    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.id)

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.firstname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.firstname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.firstname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.lastname)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.lastname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.lastname)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.gender)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.gender)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.gender)
    </div>

    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.department)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.department)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.department)
    </div>

    <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Save" />
    </p>
</fieldset>
}

<div>
@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: use trim() before assigning values

Comment: can i see some example?

Comment: In your model class, you can do this -- public string firstname { get{return firstname.trim();} set{firstname=value;} }

Comment: Probably the white spaces in the database after a value.  For example if you have a string length of 20 and the word takes up 10 you will get 10 white spaces if not inserting them correctly.  Just use trim() after collecting the value and it will fix it.

Comment: Alright i see, thank you.

Comment: These white spaces are coming from database

Comment: Huh, yess! there can be blank spaces.. jus found out the **BUGGGG!!!** in my case , in the comment below ..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a database problem. I would bet you designed your table with a lastname  property as char or nchar. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server).

How to solve it ?

- You can edit the design of your table and replace the type by varchar or nvarchar or
- You can use string.Trim() function in c# to delete white spaces but you will have to do that in every action related.

Comment: You can also validate this answer if it solves your problem :)

Comment: wasted my some precious hours.. but the issue in my case was that.. I had a blank space  `<input type="text" ...value="@(ViewBag.stnf as string)` **here** `" />`

Answer (score 1):

It has been said that all the fields except the department have spaces. Since all other fields except department are of string type, ideally you should be modifying the columns' datatypes in the DB by a type like nvarchar in SQL or varchar2() in Oracle.

As others have mentioned, you can also handle it in the code-behind as well using the Trim().

Further, scaffolding always gives you robust support for performing any CRUD operations. Please go through [this](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/examining-how-aspnet-mvc-scaffolds-the-dropdownlist-helper) post. This outlines how scaffolding works out with Entity Framework.

Cheers!