# Why MS Visual Studio passes empty spaces to SQL Server columns?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio

I am developing a Library Management System using Visual Studio 2015 as a front end and Microsoft SQL Server 2014 as back-end to store data.

This is my table design:

[image]

But when I try to pass data from Visual Studio, it saves as blank spaces to the defined length.

[image]

For example if store a text contain 10 characters on title remaining 490 store as blank space.

The highlighted are the blank space in the column. If I set the length 10 which is default I cannot store data more than 10

Is there any solution for this? is this a issue on my database or Visual Studio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between char, nchar, varchar, and nvarchar in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're using the wrong data type. `nchar` is fixed length. You need to use `nvarchar` (variable length).

Answer (score 4):

Read this before using the `datatypes` you are using. instead of `nchar` you should use `nvarchar`

## nchar [ ( n ) ]

Fixed-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and must be a value from 1 through 4,000. The storage size is two times n bytes. When the collation code page uses double-byte characters, the storage size is still n bytes. Depending on the string, the storage size of n bytes can be less than the value specified for n. The ISO synonyms for nchar are national char and national character..

## nvarchar [ ( n | max ) ]

Variable-length Unicode string data. n defines the string length and can be a value from 1 through 4,000. max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes (2 GB). The storage size, in bytes, is two times the actual length of data entered + 2 bytes. The ISO synonyms for nvarchar are national char varying and national character varying.

for more about DataTypes [Read](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms187752.aspx)