# SQL Server - what does it mean `N'some string`?

Tags: sql, sql-server

What does it mean `N'some string'` in `SQL Server`. I mean if I can use it to prevent against `SQL Injection`?
For example:
`... LIKE N'%somePattern%'`
Is `SQL Injection` safe ?

Comment: It means the string is unicode. It does nothing about sql injection.

Comment: Out of interest - what made you think it would help prevent (or was in any way related to) SQL injection?

Comment: also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025032/what-is-the-meaning-of-the-prefix-n-in-t-sql-statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the string is an `nchar` as opposed to a `char` (see [What is the difference between char, nchar, varchar, and nvarchar in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server))

It's purely about the datatype - nothing to do with SQL injection at all.

Comment: `nvarchar` as opposed to `varchar` to be precise. String literals are treated as variable length.

Answer (score 2):

The `N` has nothing to with SQL injection. You need to use it when you use unicode data

From [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx):

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without
>   the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the
>   database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.