# SQL: Maximum (n)varchar size can be stored in sql_variant

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I know that `sql_variant` cant hold items of size `nvarchar(max)`. Which is the maximum size of `nvarchar` or `varchar` that `sql_variant` can hold?

Comment: may be simple google can answer your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as pulled from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql)

> sql_variant can have a maximum length of 8016 bytes. This includes
>   both the base type information and the base type value. The maximum
>   length of the actual base type value is 8,000 bytes.

to answer your question more you can have a varchar of 8k length or a nvarchar of 4k length.

As the above documentation points out the output will never be larger then 8,000 bytes.

[more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server) on varchar and nvarchar

Answer (score 2):

> sql_variant can have a maximum length of 8016 bytes. This includes both the base type information and the base type value. The maximum length of the actual base type value is 8,000 bytes.

From [`Microsoft docs.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/sql-variant-transact-sql)