# How to save a filename with Chinese characters in SQL Server - Varchar(100)?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have filename like this: 一個例子.pdf

I want to save the filename in a SQL Server table and read it from the SQL Server table. How do you do that?

This is the code:

```
class Bestand
{
        public void Add(string filePath, DateTime fileDate, string fileName = "")
        {
            Bestand bestand = this.CurrentBestand;

            if (filePath.Length > 0 && CanReadFile(filePath))
            {
                Binary bin = new Binary();
                bin.Data = new System.Data.Linq.Binary(File.ReadAllBytes(filePath));

                bestand.BestandsDatum = fileDate;
                bestand.BestandsNaam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? Path.GetFileName(filePath) : Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fileName)[0].ToString();  

                bestand.Binary = bin;
            }
        }

        public void Save(string filePath)
        {
            byte[] buffer = Data.ToArray();
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, buffer);
        }
…
}
```

and call this to save the file:

```
documents[0].Add(beFile.Value, dtpDate.Value);
```

and call this to open the file:

```
public static void ViewBestand(IBestand bestand)
{
    string orgFilepath = Path.Combine(TempDocumentFolder, bestand.FileName);
    string filepath = orgFilepath;

    int tmpCounter = 0;
    while (File.Exists(filepath) && tmpCounter < 100)
    {
        tmpCounter++;
        filepath = Path.Combine(TempDocumentFolder, Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(orgFilepath) + "_" + tmpCounter.ToString() + Path.GetExtension(orgFilepath));
    }

    bestand.Save(filepath);
    ViewFile(filepath);
}
```

Comment: Why `VARCHAR` and not `NVARCHAR`? The latter is made for UNICODE character storage.

Comment: Because it is decided and I want to save it in a field BestandsNaam.

Comment: Is there something to encode / decode to write and read these characters in sql server from a win application?

Comment: Don't try to work around it, use `NVARCHAR`. Your client code won't need to change at all because C# is already sending the string over as `NVARCHAR` -- strings in .NET are always Unicode.

Comment: There is no "workaround". You can't save Chinese characters into a varchar field. You need to change the field to nvarchar in the *database* if you want to store Chinese characters in that field. Not change your C# application.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't knew it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the type of your column to `nvarchar(100)`. `varchar` cannot store Unicode characters, cause it's single byte, `Unicode`is double byte.

More you can read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server).

Comment: and do I had to change my code. Original code is: bestand.BestandsNaam = String.IsNullOrEmpty(fileName) ? Path.GetFileName(filePath) ; fileName;

Comment: do you mean, how to do that at all?

Comment: The suggestion is to change the field type at the database level. Not in your code.