# Entity Framework issue with varchar out parameter Error converting data type varchar to int

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I having an issue with out parameter that is return @SecurityGroup varchar(100) value is 'admin', this is the only out parameter that throws an error from sp, the other are working. The error is

> Error converting data type varchar to int

Why would it try to convert a varchar to int?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [LDR].[usp_UI_GetUserProfile] 
    @User VARCHAR(50),
    @MatchTypeID INT, 
    @SecurityGroup VARCHAR(100) OUTPUT, 
    @NumofRowsAllowed INT OUTPUT, 
    @ReturnStatus INT OUTPUT, 
    @ReturnErrorMessage NVARCHAR(4000) OUTPUT
```

Entity Framework call

```
var parameters = new[] {
                new SqlParameter("@User", UserID){Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
                new SqlParameter("@MatchTypeID", MatchTypeID){Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input},
                new SqlParameter("@SecurityGroup", DbType.String){Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output},
                new SqlParameter("@NumofRowsAllowed", DbType.Int32){Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output},
                new SqlParameter("@ReturnStatus", DbType.Int32){Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output},
                new SqlParameter("@ReturnErrorMessage", DbType.String){Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output}
            };

var results = db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("exec [LDR].[usp_UI_GetUserProfile] @UserNetID, @MatchTypeID, @SecurityGroup out, @NumofRowsAllowed out, @ReturnStatus out, @ReturnErrorMessage out", parameters[0], parameters[1], parameters[2], parameters[3], parameters[4], parameters[5]);
```

Comment: Could you provide the stored procedure logic?

Comment: [What is the difference between char, nchar, varchar, and nvarchar in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server) might help.  I notice that you have a mix of unicode and non-unicode fields mixed together.  but as @gonzzz says, the SP and the DDL would be helpful to create a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a simple thing to wrap it in a try catch block and throw a breakpoint on the catch statement. If you do that you can see what VS is trying to do that is so wrong

Comment: It's in a try catch just get the message  Error converting data type varchar to int

Comment: Entity Framework changes the varchar string to int, if I look in the out parameter it changed from varchar to System.Data.SqlDbType.Int. This is a simple SP and works perfect with ADO.NET. Microsoft might need to look into this issue deeper.