# I can't deal with char(220) in SQL Server nor in SELECT nor REPLACE or any other functions

Tags: sql, sql-server, unicode, ascii, arabic

I can't deal with an Arabic character 'ـ' SHIFT+J from keyboard, with ASCII value of 220 char(220) and UNICODE value of U+0640  .. in SQL Server nor in SELECT nor REPLACE or any other functions

I tried all possible Arabic collation

Arabic_CS_AS,
Arabic_CI_AI,
Arabic_CS_AI,
Arabic_CI_AS

I tried this but did not solve my issue

```
SELECT        ColumnName
FROM            dbo.TableName
where 
cast(ColumnName as nvarchar) like cast( N'%' + char(220) + N'%' as nvarchar)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between char, nchar, varchar, and nvarchar in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176514/what-is-the-difference-between-char-nchar-varchar-and-nvarchar-in-sql-server)

Comment: no
i tried this SELECT        ColumnName
FROM            dbo.TableName
where 
cast(ColumnName as nvarchar) like cast( N'%' + char(220) + N'%' as nvarchar)
but did not solve my issue

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, will really help us help you here.

Comment: I mean different thing... As I understand you save Arabic character (unicoded character) in column that doesn't support unicode. So values in that table aren't correct...

Comment: Also declaring a data type without it's explicit length, precision, scale, etc, is a *very* bad habit. Always make sure you declare them. `cast(ColumnName as nvarchar)` could easily be causing implicit truncation.

Comment: [U+640](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0640/index.htm) will only be `char(220)` in code page [Windows-1256](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1256) and will very much depend on the database's default collation. Have you tried using `nchar(1600)` instead?

Comment: Try `NCHAR(640)` instead of `CHAR(640)` with no `convert`. and you should always specify n/varchar lengths