# Replace NOT working!

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I have column with values that have wrong character `?`. Now I want to change it to character `b`. For this I am using this statement:

```
SELECT REPLACE(name,'?','b') from contacts;
```

But when I do this nothing's happening, it return value with `?`.

What I am doing wrong? How I can replace this?

Comment: Let's be clear: did you want the resultset to have the modification, or did you want the table's data in the `name` column to be overwritten permanently with the `?` with a character `b`?

Comment: Are you sure that the character `?` actually exists in the data? In SSMS (default settings) "Results to Grid" mode I find that sometimes it displays `?` for unicode characters that it displays properly in "Results to Text" mode.

Answer (score 7):

Are you actually trying to *change* the values in the table? In that case, you'll need to do an `UPDATE`:

```
UPDATE contacts
SET name = Replace(name,'?','b')
```

Otherwise, if you are simply trying to *retrieve* a modified value, your syntax should work just fine. (I tested it, `?` doesn't have to be escaped or anything):

```
SELECT name, Replace(name,'?','b') as Fixed
FROM contacts
```

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility that I've seen before is that the character looks like a regular old ASCII question mark but it's not really.  It's actually a different character.  I'd select the text and paste it into Notepad and then copy and paste it into my query.

Comment: That is most likely what it is.  I have seen something similar to that in Oracle.

Answer (score 4):

If your **name** column data type is `NVARCHAR` you should use `N` prefix. `NVARCHAR` and `VARCHAR` types have unicode differance. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) link for more information about differance between `NVARCHAR` and `VARCHAR` types.

```
SELECT REPLACE(name,N'?', N'b') from contacts;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
update contacts set name=replace(name, '?', 'b')
```