# Handling Alphabets (Norwegian and Danish) in Sql Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have a application that have lot of products with special alphabets like é, è, ê, ó, ò, â, and ô.

Now these alphabets gives me problem like when i store them in sql server these symbols get replaced by **?**. I also find problem during the processing.

How can i handle these.

Should i keep on using string to handle them or use something else

What should be their data-types in sql-server

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What are the current data types in your database for these fields? What are the collations? How are you inserting to the database - can you post the code?

Comment: @Oded The data types are varchar and collations are the default one. i haven't changed default collations. I am inserting the data using Linq to Entities

Comment: I think that your problem is on your insert implementation command.

Comment: Change your column types from `VARCHAR` to `NVARCHAR`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using nvarchar as the datatype? This is usually recommended when storing non-English text (the cost is more storage space). We use nvarchar for Finnish text (ä ö å), and have no problems or special processing. If writing to a stream, then make sure to use the iso-8859-1 encoding (at least for scandic languages. Eastern European languages use a different one).

If its not possible for you to change the datatype, let me know and we can come up with a different solution.

Comment: Differences between nvarchar and varchar are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar