# Using nvarchar cfsqltype in coldfusion with jtds jdbc

Tags: sql-server, jdbc, coldfusion

Firstly, my cconfig is:
Language: ColdFusion 10(and installed update 11)
DB is MS SQL Server 2012
Using the jtds jdbc(tried versions 1.2.6, 1.2.8 and 1.3.0)

I'm currently having a problem running queries where I use cfqueryparam with a cfsqltype of cf_sql_nvarchar. The problem is the page just hangs. If I look at the application log of ColdFusion, I see the error of:
"net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.JtdsPreparedStatement.setNString(ILjava/lang/String;)V The specific sequence of files included or processed is:" followed by the test filename.

I'm running a very basic select query on a nvarchar column, but the page doesn't load and that error is logged.

I know it's gotta be something to do with the jtds jdbc as if I connect through the regular sql driver it'll work perfectly.

So did anybody experience this before? If so, what was your resolution?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did a quick search and the results suggest [jtds does not support `setNString()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575194/jtds-jdbc-driver-getnstring-throws-error). I checked the driver source for 1.3.1, and as mentioned [in the comments here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12576704/104223) the method is not implemented:

> "..while getNString is implemented the code just consists of // TODO
>   Auto-generated method stub and throw new AbstractMethodError();.."

So it sounds like you may need to use [`cf_sql_varchar`, combined with the "String Format" setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10802388/what-are-the-details-for-using-cf-sql-nvarchar-in-coldfusion-10/10848136#10848136), like in previous versions. Obviously, the other option is to use a different driver (one that does support `setNString()`, such as Adobe's driver or the [MS SQL Server driver](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11774)).

Comment: Thanks, that does suggest that I can give up my search and wait for a newer version of the driver, but what confuses me is why they don't have it added it to the driver since it already does it by default. Like if I don't set sendStringParametersAsUnicode=false, then all the string parameters will be passed as nvarchar. It's like you can have either all string parameters nvarchar or all varchar, but never both for the same database

Comment: (Edit - I misread your response). Well, unfortunately yes. Since `setNString` is not implemented, the all-or-nothing sendStringParametersAsUnicode flag is the only option afaik.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `cf_sql_varchar`. `cf_sql_nvarchar` is not a valid option according to the [Documentation](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam) and you should use `cf_sql_varchar`

Comment: Scott - Unfortunately, that section of the documentation is wrong (and so is the above ;-). The [new sqltype is mentioned here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/10.0/Developing/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec0e02b-7ff3.html#WSe61e35da8d318518-9efe7cf1358680a71d-7ffe).

Comment: As Leigh said, they added it in CF10, but the documentation doesn't really reflect it that well

Comment: Yeah, once again the main docs lag behind the current release, but it is mentioned in the link above (where most people would not think of looking for it) :/

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that it does work if you don't use the jtds driver. cf_sql_nvarchar will work if you use the default ms sql driver

Comment: Yes, both Adobe and Microsoft's SQL Server driver support it. So if you are not tied to jtds, that is another alternative.