# Database should contain characters from all over the world

Tags: sql, oracle, unicode, character-encoding, iso-8859-1

I have a database where the name of many people lay in. The character set is ISO8859-15 so western europe characters. Now I want Names from all over the world join the database,e.g. Chinese and greek characters should be usable. What do I have to change? Which Character Set do I have to use?

Comment: Use nchar or nvarchar data type.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure you want [Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965589/unicode-data-type-in-sql) character encoding.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode

["ISO 8859-1 is a single-byte encoding that can represent the first 256 Unicode characters."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7048745/what-is-the-difference-between-utf-8-and-iso-8859-1)

Comment: Basically, you are right. But, Unicode is a character set. It has many character encodings. NCHAR and NVARCHAR use the UTF-16 encoding. Some RDBMSes support UTF-8 and/or UTF-8 with the BMP subset of Unicode in CHAR and VARCHAR.