# Euro sign (€) in VARCHAR column

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding

I have many of my database columns defined as VARCHAR(255) and now would like to input unicode characters (especially the € sign). 
Inserting data doesn´t show the unicode symbols, but if I update my insert statement to use NVARCHAR paramerts it is working. But why? I didn´t change the column definition from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR.

To support these symbols should I just change all paramerts from VARCHAR to NVARCHAR or should I also update the columns definition to NVARCHAR(255)?

Comment: It's because the symbol is unicode and **n**varchar supports it while varchar doesn't. Pretty much the solution here is changing column types to nvarchar and doing the same to all the parameters where you pass values that go into those columns.

Comment: you need to change the type to `nvarchar` to support unicode characters in sql-server

Comment: but you guys have any explanation why it is working with varchar columns and nvarchar paramerters in queries?

Comment: refer this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965589/unicode-data-type-in-sql

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unicode Data Type in SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10965589/unicode-data-type-in-sql)

Comment: @MK_ That is rather imprecise. The euro symbol also exists in character sets other than unicode (eg ISO-8859-15, windows-1252)

Comment: What is your database character set?  What does `SELECT * FROM database_name_parameters WHERE parameter LIKE '%CHARACTERSET' return?`

Comment: @Karthikcbe your query gives me an error (after replacing the database name of course). But the collation name is Latin1_General_CI_AS if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Varchar datatype doesn't hold Unicode character. You must convert VARCHAR(255)data type to NVARCHAR(255) inorder to hold Unicode character. 
Also update the columns definition to NVARCHAR(255)

Comment: The euro-symbol also exists in character sets other than unicode.

Answer (score 0):

use `NVARCHAR` or `change your database character` set (export, reinstall with a character set that supports the euro sign like `WE8ISO8859P15` or `AL32UTF8`, and import).

Here's an example of `NVARCHAR:`

[link](http://rextester.com/WBAZ56461)