# inserted accent into SQL

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server-2008, non-ascii-characters

i have the probleme with accent (example: é,à,è, etc).
when i inserted directly on SQL Server 2008 Management
`INSERT INTO LETTRE_VOIT (LIB_PORT) VALUES ('Payé')` it work well.
but when i load this syntax on C#, it not work.

```
 try
            {
                using (var connectionWrapper = new Connexion())
                {
                    var connectedConnection = connectionWrapper.GetConnected();


                    string sql_Syntax = Outils.LoadFileToString(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SQL/UpdateEtClotureList.sql"));
                    SqlCommand comm_Command = new SqlCommand(sql_Syntax, connectionWrapper.conn);
                    comm_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CHAUFFEUR", CHAUFFEUR);
                    comm_Command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Trans", ClotList);
                    string IdOrdre = "";
                    SqlDataReader readerOne = comm_Command.ExecuteReader();
                    while (readerOne.Read())
                    {
                        if (IdOrdre != "") IdOrdre += ",";
                        IdOrdre += readerOne["NO_ORDRE"].ToString();                    
                    }
                    return IdOrdre;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception excThrown)
            {
                throw new Exception(excThrown.Message);
            }
```

the content of UpdateEtClotureList.sql:

```
DECLARE @AfterUpdate table (
    NO_ORDRE_Temp int NOT NULL, 
    CODE_DEST_Temp varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    DATE_CLOTUR_Temp datetime NOT NULL, 
    CODE_CLIENT_Temp varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    MODAL_MODE_Temp char(1) NOT NULL,
    MODAL_PORT_Temp bit NOT NULL,
    LIVRS_EXPRS_Temp bit NOT NULL,
    ENLEV_UNITE_Temp int NOT NULL,
    NBR_COLIS_Temp int NOT NULL,
    POID_Temp decimal(10, 2) NOT NULL,
    ENLEV_CREMB_Temp decimal(10, 2)  NULL,
    ENLEV_DECL_Temp decimal(10, 2)  NULL

  )  

UPDATE ORDRE 
SET STATUT_ORDRE = 2, DATE_CLOTUR = GETDATE(), CHAUFFEUR = @CHAUFFEUR
OUTPUT inserted.NO_ORDRE, inserted.CODE_DEST, inserted.DATE_CLOTUR, inserted.CODE_CLIENT, inserted.MODAL_MODE, inserted.MODAL_PORT,inserted.LIVRS_EXPRS,inserted.ENLEV_UNITE,  inserted.NBR_COLIS,inserted.POID,inserted.ENLEV_CREMB,inserted.ENLEV_DECL INTO @AfterUpdate
WHERE STATUT_ORDRE = 1 AND (TRANSPORTEUR IN (SELECT ParsedString From dbo.ParseStringList(@Trans)))



INSERT INTO LETTRE_VOIT 

OUTPUT inserted.NO_ORDRE

select rsVoit.NOID, NO_ORDRE_Temp, rsOrdre.CODE_DEST_Temp,rsOrdre.DATE_CLOTUR_Temp, rsOrdre.CODE_CLIENT_Temp, rsOrdre.MODAL_MODE_Temp, rsOrdre.MODAL_PORT_Temp,
CASE rsOrdre.MODAL_PORT_Temp
            WHEN 'false' THEN 'Payé'
            ELSE 'Du'
        END, 
rsOrdre.LIVRS_EXPRS_Temp,
CASE rsOrdre.LIVRS_EXPRS_Temp
            WHEN 'false' THEN 'Long'
            ELSE 'Express'
        END, 
  rsOrdre.ENLEV_UNITE_Temp, LIBELLE, NBR_COLIS_Temp,POID_Temp,ENLEV_CREMB_Temp,ENLEV_DECL_Temp
from @AfterUpdate rsOrdre
inner join
(
  select CODE_DEST,MODAL_MODE, MODAL_PORT, LIVRS_EXPRS,ENLEV_UNITE, ROW_NUMBER() over (order by CODE_DEST) as NOID
  from ORDRE
  group by CODE_DEST,MODAL_MODE,MODAL_PORT,LIVRS_EXPRS,ENLEV_UNITE
) rsVoit on rsVoit.CODE_DEST = rsOrdre.CODE_DEST_Temp and rsVoit.MODAL_MODE = rsOrdre.MODAL_MODE_Temp
and rsVoit.MODAL_PORT = rsOrdre.MODAL_PORT_Temp and rsVoit.LIVRS_EXPRS = rsOrdre.LIVRS_EXPRS_Temp
and rsVoit.ENLEV_UNITE = rsOrdre.ENLEV_UNITE_Temp

LEFT JOIN T_UNITE ON rsOrdre.ENLEV_UNITE_Temp = T_UNITE.NOID

order by rsVoit.NOID, NO_ORDRE_Temp
```

the result is Pay*, instead of Payé , * is a square symbol.

Thanks you in advance.

PS: i use nvarchar instead of varchar type [image: nvarchar]

when i change the syntax:

```
....
CASE rsOrdre.MODAL_PORT_Temp
            WHEN 'false' THEN N'Payé'
            ELSE 'Du'
        END, 
rsOrdre.LIVRS_EXPRS_Temp,
.....
```

i got:
[image: result]

and when i look via SQL Profiler:
[image]

Comment: (Since you've edited that your column is nvarchar already, I suspect my previous comment was the issue - I've posted it as an answer instead)

Comment: Could this be a font problem? Do you see the é if you select to text rather than grid?

Comment: What [collation](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/30/sql-server-2005-find-database-collation-using-t-sql-and-ssms/) do you have set for your instance of SQL?

Comment: Check what encoding you used when you saved the sql script file (ANSI vs Unicode).  See my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is `LoadFileToString` corrupting the SQL? What happens if you print that out? Do you still see the é character?

What if you change the SQL to

```
WHEN 'false' THEN 'Pay' +CHAR(233)
```

Answer (score 4):

Could this be because you are using `varchar` insead of `nvarchar`?  The `nvarchar` SQL type is what you want to use if you are storing characters outside of ASCII.  `nvarchar` stores as unicode.  [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) covers the difference.

**EDIT:** Since the character in question is in the extended ASCII set, it probably isn't a problem to do with ASCII vs unicode (as pointed out by @podiluska).

**EDIT 2:** Have you checked the encoding on your sql script file (ANSI vs Unicode?).  Check out [this forum post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqldatabaseengine/thread/44b7db5a-d805-42b1-b5a4-9491986a5a1e/).  When saving the sql script file (UpdateEtClotureList.sql) choose "Save with Encoding" from the save button drop down and choose Unicode (Codepage 65001).

Comment: I don't think so. An é is an ascii character so it is fine in a varchar.

Comment: @podiluska yeah, you are [right](http://www.asciitable.com/). But, it definitely looks like an encoding problem.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO LETTRE_VOIT (LIB_PORT) VALUES ('Payé')
```

does work, but in general you should use:

```
INSERT INTO LETTRE_VOIT (LIB_PORT) VALUES (N'Payé')
```

with the `N` to indicate that it's a unicode string.

Comment: @podiluska hmm - you're right with this particular character, I thought it was "just another unicode character". In general it holds true though.

Comment: absolutely - that was my initial thought

Answer (score 2):

After checking NVARCHAR columns and N'' Unicode string literals, my guess is that Outils.LoadFileToString() does not use the correct [Encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to read the .sql file.