# Function returning string with spaces in between each character, issues when trying to remove spaces

Tags: .net, sql, vb.net

### Okay so i found what was wrong, it was in the sql convert function. I was converting to varchar(30) when it was supposed to be nvarchar(30).   To see the difference. [What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

I guess this might be a silly question but i can't seem to be able to remove some sort of space from a string returned by this function. I guess the first real question is why is this function returning a string like this                      "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" when we're saving to the database like this "1234789". Second question is why something like this

```
Replace("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9","\p{Zs}","")
```

or

```
Replace("1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9"," ","")
```

Is not working, i have a feeling its because of the characters inbetween look like spaces but are not.

[image: My Watch]

```
    Private Shared Function GetEncryptedPmtField(lhID As Integer, accountId As Integer, fieldName As String)
        Dim openKeyCmd = String.Format("OPEN SYMMETRIC KEY somekey DECRYPTION BY PASSWORD = '{0}'",     ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("Somethingsomething"))
        Const closeKeyCmd As String = "CLOSE SYMMETRIC KEY somekey"

        Dim command As New SqlCommand()
        command.Connection = New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Something").ConnectionString)
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        command.CommandText = String.Format("{0} SELECT convert(varchar(30),decryptbykey({1})  FROM  paymentacct WHERE lh_id = @lhid AND id = @id ; {2}", openKeyCmd, fieldName, closeKeyCmd)
        command.Parameters.AddRange({New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "lhid", .Value = lhID}, New SqlParameter With {.ParameterName = "id", .Value = accountId}})
        command.Connection.Open()
        Dim baNum = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString()
        command.Connection.Close()
        Return baNum
    End Function
```

Comment: If they're not spaces, then what are they?  Set a breakpoint on the link and view the contents of the variable in hex.

Comment: Call `Char.GetNumericValue()` on each char of the string; I bet your database contains NVarChar, UCS-16, or something like that, not Unicode.

Comment: As @DourHighArch said, you have some encoding problems. Don't try to solve it with regex or replace. Solve your encoding problem.

Comment: I would be interested in seeing the object type returned by command.ExecuteScalar(). MSDN says it returns a generic object, it will be possible to find out what type is actually being returned and then better understand its ToString() method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you everyone for the help, here is the fix.
So, the issue was in the type I was converting the encrypted field to. I was using varchar instead of nvarchar.

```
  SELECT convert(varchar(30),decryptbykey(keyname) FROM  paymentacct
```

to

```
 SELECT convert(nvarchar(30),decryptbykey(keyname))  FROM  paymentacct
```

Note the varchar -> nvarchar change in the convert function

Answer (score -1):

Give Regex \s a try

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(Regex.Replace("12 3  4   5   ",@"\s+",""));
```

If you are using String.Replace then it is not going to recognize "\p{Zs}" as a space.
You need to be using Regex.  The question is not tagged Regex.

Are you saying in the database it is the correct value?

Comment: While that does work for the example you put up it does not work in this instance. http://i.imgur.com/qCroz.png

Comment: Then you need to post actual data. Do a copy paste of the problem data.  Most likely it is a weird space.

Comment: Straight from the watch | Name | Value | Type|

Regex.Replace(GetEncryptedPmtField(28,142,"routing"),"\p{Zs}","") | "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9" | String

Comment: Those spaces in you comment are regular char(32).  What is in watch may be formatted.  I mean like copy paste closer to the actual output.

Comment: @BrianRizo Also, set your watch to display in hex.  That should help.