# how to fix arabic characters saved in my table

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

i need your help in this as i am stuck .

i have 2 tables the collation of some fields is arabic ( address , client Name ) bith these fields collation are arabic .

table one ( uploaded_data ) fields -----> client_name , client_address

i use upload excel file to table1 ( uploaded_data)  and its succesfully work 100% and the address and name coming in arabic 
means there is no problems in this table

i add trigger on insert for table 1 to save data in table 2 by using

select * from insrted

table two ( client_Files ) fields ------>client_name , client_address

the problem that when the trigger fired and the data saved to table 2 the records not showing known characters its coming rabish because i use the parameter to save the data

if i use the field direct without using the parameter its working fine

so can any one advice and note taht all fields name and address are arabic collation

please advice

Comment: What is your parameter's data type? is it varchar or nvarchar?

Comment: Could you please answer VahiD's question?.Use NVARCHAR to store UNICODE data. 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar

Comment: varchar for all fields

Answer (score 0):

Check if your column type is NVARCHAR instead of Varchar .Because NVARCHAR supports unicode.

Comment: i will check and feedback