# How to change sql generated by linq-to-entities?

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I am querying a MS SQL database using Linq and Entity Framework Code First. The requirement is to be able to run a `WHERE SomeColumn LIKE '%sometext'`clause against the table.

This, on the surface, is a simple requirement that could be accomplished using a simple Linq query like this:

```
var results = new List<MyTable>();
using(var context = new MyContext())
{
  results = context.MyTableQueryable
    .Where(x => x.SomeColumn.EndsWith("sometext"))
    .ToList();
}
// use results
```

However, this was not effective in practice. The problem seems to be that the column `SomeColumn` is not varchar, rather it's a char(31). This means that if a string is saved in the column that is less than 31 characters then there will be spaces added on the end of the string to ensure a length of 31 characters, and that fouls up the `.EndsWith()` query.

I used SQL Profiler to lookup the exact sql that was generated from the `.EndsWith()` method. Here is what I found:

```
--previous query code removed for brevity
WHERE [Extent1].[SomeColumn] LIKE N'%sometext'
```

So *that* is interesting. I'm not sure what the `N` means before `'%sometext'`. (I'll Google it later.) But I do know that if I take the same query and run it in SSMS without the `N` like this:

```
--previous query code removed for brevity
WHERE [Extent1].[SomeColumn] LIKE '%sometext'
```

Then the query works fine. Is there a way to get Linq and Entity Framework to drop that `N` from the query?

Comment: ``N`` basically means it's looking at your string as being a varchar, which is probably your issue.

Comment: [VARCHAR and NVARCHAR](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar). As for the error you are getting, it does seem strange, not an issue I have experienced, but then again I only use `NVARCHAR`s in my recent databases without issue.

Comment: @XN16 - I prefer nvarchar as well. Unfortunately I do not have the liberty to use it in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this...

```
.Where(x => x.SomeColumn.Trim().EndsWith("sometext"))
```

Comment: oof. Thanks, this works. Now I need to write the `.Trim()` method into my expression tree generator too.... ugh. I was hoping I could avoid that. :-)

Comment: For those who are interested, this results in the following query: `WHERE LTRIM(RTRIM([Extent1].[SomeColumn])) LIKE N'%sometext'`

Answer (score 1):

Just spoke to my colleague who had a similar issue, see if the following works for you:

```
[Column(TypeName = "varchar")]
public string SomeColumn
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

Apparently setting the type on the column mapping will force the query to recognise it as a `VARCHAR`, where a string is normally interpreted as an `NVARCHAR`.

Comment: Is this intended to generate a column that is varchar? (I cannot change the existing database.) Or, is this intended to cause EF to treat the char(31) column as a varchar?

Comment: @quakkels I believe it is the second option, it will treat it as a varchar.