# SSIS-handling non English characters-Truncation error

Tags: sql, ssis

loading non-English characters like Ç,è,Ü,Å from UTF-8 encoded text file into SQL Server Table field with Varchar data type SSIS Flat File connection manager throws data truncation errors even though number of characters in flat file is same as defined as in SQL table field

Example:like say there is 20 non english characters,even though the table is defined as varchar(20) it throws a truncation error.Any idea to resolve the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cant put unicode characters into a varchar field, it will corrupt them, if it works at all. Use [`nvarchar(20)`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/147302/2589202) instead.