# SQL Server 2008 r2: vietnamese letters are not stored correctly

Tags: sql-server, unicode

The problem is the following: I have a column of type nvarchar, collation is set to Vietnamese_CI_AS. I insert some data containing vietnamese letters (using MS SQL Server Management studio). And then it is not displayed correctly in SQL Server Management studio and application.

Data:

### [image: Data]

Result

### [image: Result]

Any suggestions?

Comment: what is the data type of the Name column? - it has to be nvarchar or have the correct collation

Comment: also if you are writing sql you need to use N 
INSERT INTO MYTABLE (NAME) VALUES (N'my vietnamese')
N signifies unicode to sql server

Comment: @Gavin you are absolutely right, thanks alot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must always declare N before inserting any values. N stands for national language character set.

Have a look at this post to get a better understanding.

[What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)