# error on converting persian characters from excel to sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to convert an excel file to sql. 
but i'm getting below error.
[image]

when i change on truncation value to "ignore" , the convert process will be complete but persian characters will be seen as "?".

Comment: Are the destination columns NVARCHAR?  They should be if they're going to accept unicode text.

Comment: it is varchar not nvarchar. is it the reason?

Comment: I think I already answered that question in my comment.

Comment: so please help me for next problem. i want to change destaination type from varchar to nvarchar but my table has some Foreign Keys. so i can't drop and recreate my table.

Comment: Well, I'm not exactly sure about that one, sorry.  But either way, that's a different question and should be a new post per Stack Overflow rules.

Comment: Could you please write your comment as answer so I could select an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that all your destination columns are `NVARCHAR` if they are going to be accepting Unicode text.

See here for a detailed explanation:  [What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Answer (score 0):

As you know, import excel files to SQL server database is doing by Access Engine, in most of the cases that you see this error, it could be solved by below method:

At first, you create an access file and save it in MDB format (this format could be used in SQL server),
and then import your excel file to this Access.mdb file, when all your data is complete, you can import this MDB file from the SQL server to your database,