# SQL Server data type and size

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need guidance pertaining to SQL standards. I am given a task to develop a small database and my manager expects me to follow data type and size standards, appropriately use int and big int, if First name use proper data type varchar or char, mainly size not abruptly varchar(60) or varchar(75) but use either varchar(128) or varchar(64) or varchar(256). I am not sure about standards. Please guide me with respect to size, how much difference does it makes if i declare varchar(60) instead of standard varchar(256). What is the list , does it starts from varchar(8) and ends up in varchar(256)

Comment: Please read char and varchar document on the msdb.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: Sorry, but while we're happy to help with problems, if it's something you could trivially look up in documentation, you really should do that yourself.

Comment: @Thomas_ITsavvy you would generally avoid varchar and char.  Your better of using nvarchar

Comment: There is not really standard. As a rule of thumb you shuold use the smallest size that you expect or allow. Also, this question is off topic in stackoverflow as it's answers will be primarly opinon based.

Answer (score 0):

`varchar` will only use as much space as the length of the string (up to the procided maximum).  `char` will used a fixed size regardless of the size of the data stored.  There are nbo "standards" but here are some guidelines from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx):

> - Use `char` when the sizes of the column data entries are consistent.
> - Use `varchar` when the sizes of the column data entries vary considerably.
> - Use `varchar(max)` when the sizes of the column data entries vary considerably, and the size might exceed 8,000 bytes.

There are also not standards with regard to the proper length of a `varchar`.  Common sense would say to use the maximum size that your data could be - 256  characters for a last name seems more that reasonable.  There's no benefit that I'm aware of to using multiples of any number for the size since it's stored as a variable length with a null terminator.

It sounds like your organization may have some specific standards (use of multiples of 8, etc.) that you should probably adhere to, but nothing industry-wide that I'm aware of.

Comment: Seconding that "There are also not standards with regard to the proper length of a varchar.". There is no difference in performance, storage or otherwise between a VARCHAR(32) and a VARCHAR(40) (assuming all data going into the field is less than 32 characters and the 40 is "just in case".

Comment: I think in this day and age of cheap memory and storage not using nvarchar (given the potential problems avoided by using unicode) is not worth the future potential hassle of dealing with code page errors http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar.