# Interview questions sql

Tags: mysql, sql

What is nvarchar2 in sql or MySQL

Comment: http://google.com/search?q=nvarchar2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a data type used to store string values up to 16 bits long.

Comment: Yes, here's a list of all available data types with their definitions:

[DATATYPES](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_datatypes_general.asp)

For a more detailed explanation of varchars/nvarchars: [CLICK HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)