# Dynamic MS SQL Variable Parsing incorrectly

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have got an issue with Dynamic Variable Parsing incorrectly and I don't know a way around it.

Here is an example:

```
DECLARE @tableName varchar(20),
    @columnName varchar(20),
    @prompt varchar(20)

DECLARE @dynSQL varchar(500)


set @tableName = '[A1-ExciseESN]'
set @columnName = '[Anode Excise ESN (A1)]'

@dynSQL = 'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName +'
([trav num], '+@columnName+')
Select [trav num], '+@columnName+'
FROM [temprmi$] t1
PIVOT(min([Lvl1 Trace Data])
FOR [Prompt Text] IN ('+@columnName+'
   )
   ) AS PVTTable
     where '+@columnName+' is not null and [trav num] not in (select [trav num] from '+@tableName+')'


print @dynSQL
```

Here is the output of the `print @dynSQL`

```
INSERT INTO [A1-ExciseESN]
([trav num], [Anode Excise ESN (A) 
Select [trav num], [Anode Excise ESN (A
FROM [temprmi$] t1
PIVOT(min([Lvl1 Trace Data])
FOR [Prompt Text] IN ([Anode Excise ESN (A
   )
   ) AS PVTTable
     where [Anode Excise ESN (A is not null and [trav num] not in (select [trav num] from [A1-ExciseESN])
```

I've tried several methods but can't seem to make it work.
Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: In Dynamic SQL, you can save yourself some syntax headache and readability by just using your variable name in the string and then encapsulating the whole string with a REPLACE() to substitute out your variable with its value at the end.  For example: `'INSERT INTO ' + @tableName +' String two'`  becomes `REPLACE('INSERT INTO @tableName, String two','@tableName',@tableName)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use correct types `SYSNAME` for idetifiers, `NVARCHAR(MAX)` for query
2. Use `REPLACE` instead of concatenating it will be much easier to debug especially when you need string literals
3. Consider using `QUOTENAME` function

Code:

```
DECLARE 
    @tableName  SYSNAME,
    @columnName SYSNAME,
    @prompt     VARCHAR(20),
    @dynSQL     NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @tableName  = QUOTENAME('A1-ExciseESN');
SET @columnName = QUOTENAME('Anode Excise ESN (A1)');

SET @dynSQL = 
N'INSERT INTO  <tableName> 
 ([trav num], <columnName>)
Select [trav num], <columnName>
FROM [temprmi$] t1
PIVOT(min([Lvl1 Trace Data])
FOR [Prompt Text] IN (<columnName>)
   ) AS PVTTable
     where <columnName> is not null 
        and [trav num] not in (select [trav num] from <tableName> )'

SET @dynSQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@dynSQL, '<tableName>', @tableName),
               '<columnName>', @columnName);

PRINT @dynSQL;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/382610)**</kbd>

Output:

```
INSERT INTO  [A1-ExciseESN] 
 ([trav num], [Anode Excise ESN (A1)])
Select [trav num], [Anode Excise ESN (A1)]
FROM [temprmi$] t1
PIVOT(min([Lvl1 Trace Data])
FOR [Prompt Text] IN ([Anode Excise ESN (A1)])
   ) AS PVTTable
     where [Anode Excise ESN (A1)] is not null 
       and [trav num] not in (select [trav num] from [A1-ExciseESN] )
```

Comment: Additional Question - what does the `N'` stand for at the beginning of `dynSQL`?

Comment: [nvarchar, versus varchar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Comment: @TangoAlee Link above give good description. NVARCHAR() and N'' before string means support for unicode characters.

Comment: I posted another question - This worked great now I'm supplying the `@columnname` and `@tablename` from a cursor and it isn't supplying the `[]` any more. see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33486521/dynamic-ms-sql-variable-parsing-incorrectly-from-cursor

Comment: @TangoAlee Just use `QUOTENAME` function (see point 3), but you've got this answer already in your new question

Answer (score 2):

You've defined:

```
@columnName varchar(20),
```

But you're assigning:

```
set @columnName = '[Anode Excise ESN (A1)]'
```

columnname needs to be at least varchar(23).  the column name you're using is 23 characters long.

Comment: Thank you - I would have never checked that!