# Dynamic SQL Server Variable Parsing Incorrectly from Cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I'm having trouble parsing a variable from a lookup cursor populated by a lookup table.

It is very similar to my previous question here:

[Dynamic MS SQL Variable Parsing incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33443091/dynamic-ms-sql-variable-parsing-incorrectly)

But now I'm supplying the `@tablename` and `@columnname` from a lookup table, which is causing me to miss the `[` and `]` around the column names.

```
DECLARE 
    @tableName SYSNAME,
    @columnName SYSNAME,
    @col2 SYSNAME,
    @prompt SYSNAME,
    @dynSQL varchar(MAX);

Declare cLookup CURSOR FOR
    SELECT * 
    FROM LookupTbl

OPEN cLookup

FETCH NEXT FROM cLookup INTO @tableName, @columnName, @prompt

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    set @dynSQL = N'INSERT INTO <tableName>
        ([trav num], <columnname>)
        Select [trav num], <columnname>
        FROM [temprmi$] t1
        PIVOT(min([Lvl1 Trace Data])
        FOR [Prompt Text] IN (<columnname>)
           ) AS PVTTable
             where <columnname> is not null and [trav num] not in (select [trav num] from <tablename>)'

    SET @dynSQL = REPLACE(REPLACE(@dynSQL, '<tablename>', @tablename),'<columnname>',@columnname);

    print @dynSQL
    Print 'Done with '+ @tableName
    FETCH NEXT FROM cLookup
    INTO @tableName, @columnName, @prompt

end
Close cLookup
Deallocate cLookup
```

Lookup Table:

```
TableName       ColumnName                  Prompt
A1-ExciseESN    Anode Excise ESN (A1)       NULL
A1-Excise DT    Anode ExciseDate&Time(A1)   NULL
A1-Excise DT-1  AnodeExcieDate&Time(A1)-1   NULL
StackFixture    Stack Fixture               NULL
```

See output below. I am missing the `[` and `]` around the column names.

Output:

```
INSERT INTO A1-ExciseESN
        ([trav num], Anode Excise ESN (A1))
        Select [trav num], Anode Excise ESN (A1)
        FROM [temprmi$] t1
        PIVOT(min([Lvl1 Trace Data])
        FOR [Prompt Text] IN (Anode Excise ESN (A1))
           ) AS PVTTable
             where Anode Excise ESN (A1) is not null and [trav num] not in (select [trav num] from A1-ExciseESN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a function called `QUOTENAME` which will do exactly that:

```
SET @dynSQL = REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                @dynSQL
                ,'<tablename>'
                , QUOTENAME(@tablename)
                )
              ,'<columnname>',QUOTENAME(@columnname)
               )
```

e.g. `select QUOTENAME('abc')` = `'[abc]'`

[QUOTENAME (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx)