# Python cx_Oracle query speed

Tags: python, oracle, dataframe, cx-oracle

## Problem

It takes a long time to query our Oracle database with python using cx_Oracle.

## Method

I connect to oracle db using cx_Oracle, and query using a standard SQL line like:

```sql
select * from t1;
```

Results are returned as a pandas dataframe.

## Observations

- Querying from Spyder and Jupyter Notebooks are equally slow.
- Querying from an SQL client like DBeaver returns results in ~1/10th the time.

## Caveat

I have not tested if this holds true when I include row-limits in the cx-Oracle queries.

Comment: Your question is a bit generic. Without additional information (like what data you are querying and what code you are using to query it) I can't answer your question. I find the performance of cx_Oracle adequate in most cases, somewhat slower than the equivalent C program but with a lot less effort. Since you are using a dataframe that implies you are using something like Pandas. Try using cx_Oracle directly as well.

Answer (score 2):

- Tune the application architecture
- [Tune the
  Database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgdba/index.html)
- [Tune the SQL](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgsql/index.html)
- [Tune the
  network](https://static.rainfocus.com/oracle/oow19/sess/1553616880266001WLIh/PF/OOW19_Net_CON4641_1569022126580001esUl.pdf). Particularly the SDU size and socket buffer sizes.  (If it helps, there is an alternative description of these in the [Oracle Net Easy Connect Plus Whitepaper](https://download.oracle.com/ocomdocs/global/Oracle-Net-19c-Easy-Connect-Plus.pdf)).
- [Tune
  cx_Oracle](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html),
  particularly `Cursor.arraysize`

Answer (score 0):

@Christopher Jones and @Anthony Tuininga pointed to next level answers in solving why queries were returning so slowly. In my #Caveat section, I noted that I had no

```sql
WHERE rownum < 10
```

in my queries. Including this did indeed reduce query times. My bad.

Also, a command like

```sql
create table t1 as
select *
from table1
```

results in instant feedback, since nothing is being received from the db.
It was just a matter of issuing a query that demanded a lot of data back. An SQL client has those row limits built in to prevent people like me from asking these questions! :)

Answer (score 0):

## Addressing Slow Write Speeds

When writing to Oracle, all df columns which are String objects are by default converted to [CLOB](https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.10.1.2/ref/rrefclob.html) (Character large objects), which are max 2,147,483,647 in length). This means that tables are very likely far larger than necassary.

When using df.to_sql, you typically use something like the following:

```py
df.to_sql("tablename"
        connection_string,
        schema='myschema',
        if_exists='replace',
        index=False
        )
```

However, omitting the optional parameter dtypes may result in CLOBs.

## A Solution

To overcome this, you either manually provide dtypes:

```py
df.to_sql("tablename"
        connection_string,
        schema='myschema',
        if_exists='replace',
        index=False,
        dtype={"RUN_DT": sa.types.DateTime(),
        "fname": sa.types.VARCHAR(length=50),
        "lname": sa.types.VARCHAR(length=250),
        "FROM_DT": sa.types.DateTime(),
        "TO_DT": sa.types.DateTime(),
        "UUID": sa.types.VARCHAR(length=50)}
        )
```

## A Better, Generalized Solution

But what if you have many tables and many columns and you need a generalized solution?

@Parfait provided the *perfect* solution to this issue on SO [**here**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34384664/5825523).