# Defining data type when using pandas.to_sql()

Tags: python, pandas, postgresql

I am writing a pandas Dataframe to a redshift database using `pandas.to_sql()` as so:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd

conn = create_engine('postgresql://user:password@redshift-url.amazonaws.com:5439/db')

dataframe.to_sql('table_name', conn, index=False, if_exists='replace', schema='schema_name')
```

I this dataframe I have `timestamp` column which looks like this `2020-03-02`, but when I write it to db it gets stored as a varchar and I cant use this column to plot graphs which require timestamp format.

Is there a way to define the column type when writing data to a db with pandas.to_sql()? I do not want to create a view or another table out of the one I am writing because then I would need to drop the current table as the other one would be related to the original one and I would get an error `cant drop table because other objects depend on it`.

Comment: You could use `sqlalchemy.types` and specify a schema dictionary  as `dtype` to the `pd.to_sql` function, check the accepted answer in this link - [pandas to_sql all columns as nvarchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34383000/pandas-to-sql-all-columns-as-nvarchar)  Check [here](https://github.com/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/blob/master/lib/sqlalchemy/types.py) for supported sqlalchemy types.

Answer (score 5):

## use [sqlalchemy.types](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/dialects/postgresql.html#postgresql-data-types)

for your time stamp column:

```
from sqlalchemy import types 

sql_types =  {'date' : types.TIMESTAMP(0)}
```

then change your `dataframe.to_sql` call to include the following arguments.

```
dataframe.to_sql('table_name', conn, index=False, 
                if_exists='replace', schema='schema_name',
                dtype=sql_types)
```

Comment: Hm, for some reason the datatype is still a varchar.

Comment: @JonasPalačionis can you open the table to see the created datatypes?