# How to define varchar2

Tags: sql, sql-server, ddl, varchar2

I need to add a column with `varchar2` data type in teradata sql ,

for example

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name varchar2 (20);
```

But in teradata its not taking `varchar2` as a defined type name.

Comment: You have tagged sql server, but the question says teradata. Which one are you working with?

Answer (score 5):

`varchar2` is an Oracle-specific datatype, not defined in the ANSI SQL standard. You should use the standard `varchar` type instead:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD column_name VARCHAR(20);
```

Comment: Here's a link to a list of Oracle to Teradata translation rules. https://teradataworld.wordpress.com/2013/10/27/oracle-to-teradata-migration-guidelines/

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `NVARCHAR(20)` - pay attention to that extra `N` in the type name, as it allows you to store [Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) strings.