# Best size of comment - SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, comments, varchar, nvarchar, ntext

Best length of comment on app is 4000? I want to know standard of social network.
How can I show it on SQL Server?

Is it must be `nvarchar(?)` or `varchar(?)` or `ntext` or ...?

Thanks for your help

Comment: I have no idea how anyone could possibly answer this.  It's going to be highly dependent on the specific application you are building.  There will be trade-offs that you need to understand and to choose the best approach for your particular application.  You can look at the StackOverflow data model but that may or may not be the set of trade-offs that you want to make

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: @marc_s yes and thanks

Comment: @JustinCave okay thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it depends.. Facebook comments can be up to 8000 chars. Twitter only 160 (includes twitter space)

If you are using SQL Server, heard `ntext` will be deprecated. Some blogs suggest to go with `varchar`, until and unless you have a very specific business with respect to unicode chars.

Comment: I highly recommended to consider **n**varchar(*whatever*) more details here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar

Comment: @PavelKovalev add a answer , I can mark your answer

Comment: @Mohi your question was put on hold so it is not possible to add an  answer. But I appreciate if you vote for my comment 