# error in creating table in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want to run the following sql command in phpmyadmin:

```
create table files(messageId INT NOT NULL, 
messageBlockId INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
data NVARCHAR(MAX), 
Signatures NVARCHAR(MAX), 
owner INT NOT NULL);
```

I am gitting this error:

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'MAX), Signatures NVARCHAR(MAX), owner INT NOT NULL)' at line 1

What should I do? I would have used the GUI in phpmyadmin to create table but it does not show NVARCHAR as datatype.

Edit: I tried to change NVARCHAR(MAX) to VARCHAR(MAX) but the error still exists. Its Okay if I use varchar but how do I remove the error?

Thanks :)

Comment: Any update for this ?

Answer (score 2):

You should use `VARCHAR(MAX)`, not  `NVARCHAR(MAX)`

Comment: but my code(for which I am creating the database) deals with nvarchar. I have a line in code saying getNString() in java. What is the difference between varchar(max) and nvarchar(max)?

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar

Comment: Try giving a number instead of MAX.

Comment: And also take note of the reserved words in Mysql https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/keywords.html