# Stored Procedure error when called from Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I'm trying to build a simple project that will run my stored procedure .

When I execute the SP through SQL-Server it works fine :

```
EXECUTE RunSSISPackage1        
  @folder_name1 = N'SSIS projects',
  @project_name1=N'CalculateReports',
  @package_name1=N'CalculateReports.dtsx',
  @param1 = N'2017-04-01 00:00:00',
  @param1name = N'startDate'
```

My controller:

```
public IActionResult Test()
{
    using (var cmd = _context.Database.GetDbConnection().CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "RunSSISPackage";
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        // set some parameters of the stored procedure
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@package_name1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        {
            Value = "N'CalculateReports.dtsx'"
        });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@folder_name1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        {
            Value = "N'SSIS projects'"
        });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@project_name1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        {
            Value = "N'CalculateReports.dtsx'"
        });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        {
            Value = "N'2017-04-01 00:00:00'"
        });
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
        {
            Value = "N'startDate'"
        });
        if (cmd.Connection.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            cmd.Connection.Open();

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        return View();
    }
}
```

I'm getting an error :

> Cannot access the package or the package does not exist. Verify that the package exists and that the user has permissions to it.

This error occurs when the parameters of `package_name\folder_name\project_name` is not sent correctly.

How can I pass prefix values as a parameter?

Comment: You don't need the `N'...'` wrap in your code, that's only a SQL Server thing for unicode conversion. Instead, do this: `Value = "CalculateReports.dtsx"`

Comment: Still doesn't work.. same error appears @DavidG

Comment: And you've removed the `N'...'` from *all* your parameters?

Comment: @DavidG Never mind, I also passed a wrong project name :X , I hate that tiny mistakes. Thank you, it solved my problem. If you want you can post it as answer and I'll approve.

Comment: Please only used needed tags. ASP.NET has absolutely nothing to do with your question, so I've removed those tags

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `N'...'` wrap in your code, that's only a SQL Server thing for unicode conversion. For example, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar). So when you're doing that, you're actually passing the package name of `N'CalculateReports.dtsx'` which obviously doesn't exist.

Instead, do this `Value = "CalculateReports.dtsx"`, for example:

```
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@package_name1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
{
    Value = "CalculateReports.dtsx"
});
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@folder_name1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
{
    Value = "SSIS projects"
});
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@project_name1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
{
    Value = "CalculateReports.dtsx"
});
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
{
    Value = "2017-04-01 00:00:00"
});
cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@param1name", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
{
    Value = "startDate"
});
```

Comment: Thank you. In 5 minutes I'll approve this.