# What SQL collation should I use to store multi-language character?

Tags: sql-server, collation, multilingual

I have a Database and my users are from all around the world because of this I should store the inputs in any language type.

By default my SQL collation is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CA_AS` but this collation can not store Russian language.

What SQL collation I should use to store any language type like Japanese, Persian, English,Russian and ....?

Comment: What makes you think you can't use Russian with that collation? (PS It's collation, not collection)

Comment: i saved one and look at my table and i saw that has been converted to "????????"

Comment: What data type do you have in the table? I'm going to guess it's `VARCHAR` instead of `NVARCHAR`?

Comment: varchar(50), you mean i should use nvarchar(50)?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: wow it works, Thank you so so much

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem isn't the collation you are using, but the data type you are using to store text.

Your table is using `VARCHAR` type when you should be using `NVARCHAR`. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    SomeColumn VARCHAR(50)
)
```

Should be:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable
(
    SomeColumn NVARCHAR(50)
)
```

For more info on the difference, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar).