# Encoding issue in MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to execute the below-mentioned query in MSSQL.

```
insert into STUDENT (STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_MARKS, SID) values ('索引', 10, 2)
```

> STUDENTNAME column is of type NVARCHAR.

After execution of the above query. The student name getting inserted is: **??**

I understand that the above issue is related to encoding and so I modified the above query by adding N, as shown below :

```
insert into STUDENT (STUDENT_NAME, STUDENT_MARKS, SID) values (N'索引', 10, 2)
```

The above query is running as expected and is inserting the Chinese characters successfully.

Question: I'm using JDBC to execute this insert query, So do I need to proceed all the values with N as shown above. Or there is some other setting at the driver level to fix this?

Comment: can you show us the JDBC Connection ?

Answer (score 2):

I found this on a [Microsoft article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms186939.aspx),

> Prefix Unicode character string constants with the letter N. Without
>   the N prefix, the string is converted to the default code page of the
>   database. This default code page may not recognize certain characters.

`N` denotes that the string is in Unicode (the N actually stands for National language character set), which means that you are passing an NCHAR, NVARCHAR or NTEXT value, as opposed to CHAR, VARCHAR or TEXT.

Please follow [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) post:

[Difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Further to your question, if you are using `INSERT` queries to insert the records in the table, then **YES** you have to add an `N` before every string value.