# How to store arabic language in SQL Server by using stored procedure parameter?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to insert and update Arabic language into SQL Server by using stored procedure and parameters. I checked the other posts all they said you use `nvarchar(100)` or use `N'الاسم العربي'`.

My case is different: I am using stored procedure and parameters, how to put N before the parameter `@patient_Name_Arabic` this is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[UPDATE_PATIENTS]
    @Patient_name VARCHAR(50),
    @Age INT,
    @Mobile VARCHAR(50),
    @Email VARCHAR(50),
    @Address VARCHAR(50),
    @Gender INT,
    @Patient_id VARCHAR(50),
    @Natid INT,
    @Patient_no INT,
    @insurance_card IMAGE,
    @ID_card IMAGE,
    @patient_Name_Arabic NVARCHAR(50)
AS 
    UPDATE [Patients]
    SET [Patient_Name] = @Patient_name, 
        [Age] = @Age,
        [Mobile] = @Mobile,
        [Email] = @Email,
        [Address] = @Email,
        [Gender] = @Gender,
        [Patient_id] = @Patient_id,
        [Natid] = @Natid,
        [insurance_card] = @insurance_card,
        [ID_card] = @ID_card,
        patient_Name_Arabic = @patient_Name_Arabic
    WHERE Patient_no = @Patient_no
```

I tried to put `N` before parameter `@patient_Name_Arabic` but it's not working.

```
N'@patient_Name_Arabic' or N"@patient_Name_Arabic" or N(@patient_Name_Arabic)
```

What is the correct way in my case to store Arabic language ?

Comment: For unicode chars, please use NVARCHAR as datatype

Comment: The `N` is needed only for string literals to denote a Unicode string. The stored procedure parameter is already nvarchar (Unicode) so Unicode characters will be stored as long as the table column is nvarchar and you pass a Unicode value.

Comment: Read: [What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar) You have declared your parameters of type _varchar_, the sql engine tries to satisfy your request

Comment: Just use `NVarchar(50)` instead of `Varchar(50)` when declaring parameters

Comment: **Side note:** `image` data type will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using this data type in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Use `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between varchar and nvarchar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/144283/what-is-the-difference-between-varchar-and-nvarchar)

Comment: A number of comments state that the OP has used `varchar` parameters. That is not true - `patient_Name_Arabic` is defined as `nvarchar` in the above code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution I am using in my c# application the following code :

```
param[10] = new SqlParameter("@patient_Name_Arabic", SqlDbType.VarChar, 50);
            param[10].Value = patient_Name_Arabic;
```

I changed SqlDbType.VarChar, 50 
to        SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50

```
param[10] = new SqlParameter("@patient_Name_Arabic", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);
            param[10].Value = patient_Name_Arabic;
```

and its working correct and save arabic language i tried before in stored procedure in SQL server , i changed the application code also then its worked.
Thank you for help