# UTF-8 charecter - UC2-Decimal(150).How to handle this char?

Tags: utf-8

In my app some UTF characters like – whose value is UC2-Decimal(150),UC2-Hex(0096),UTF8-Hex(C296) which is fetched from some website, cannot be displayed properly in the browser.
It displays some unwanted characters.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I don't understand your notation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what UC2-Decimal and UC2-Hex mean, but you seem to be talking about Unicode code point 150 (decimal) or 0x96 (hex). This Unicode character exists but it isn't what you are looking for: it's an obscure control character in the C1 series known as "SPA". Presumably this is the problem!

The character which you actually copied in your question is U+2013, known as "EN DASH", a valid character. Its UTF-8 representation would be the three-byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x93.

Comment: Yeah am talking about Unicode point 150(decimal).This charecter gets displayed as some junk charecter in my app.How do i handle it in app

Comment: You don't. U+0096 (decimal 150) is not the character you are looking for. I misspoke when I said it didn't exist (I will correct my answer in just a minute) but it's an obscure unprintable control character known as SPA. [Here](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf) is the official reference.

Comment: Worth noting that OP probably wanted to refer to UCS-2, used by default in SQL Server ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008043/ucs-2-and-sql-server)).