# When must we use NVARCHAR/NCHAR instead of VARCHAR/CHAR in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, unicode, collation, nvarchar

Is there a rule when we must use the Unicode types?

I have seen that most of the European languages (German, Italian, English, ...) are fine in the same database in VARCHAR columns.

I am looking for something like:

1. If you have Chinese --> use NVARCHAR
2. If you have German and Arabic --> use NVARCHAR

What about the collation of the server/database?

I don't want to use always NVARCHAR like suggested here
[What are the main performance differences between varchar and nvarchar SQL Server data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366/varchar-vs-nvarchar-performance)

Comment: Both the two most upvoted questions are **wrong**. It has nothing to do with "store different/multiple languages". You can support Spanish characters like `ñ` and English, with just common varchar.

Comment: I just posted an answer explaining and also providing updated approach on how to deal with it.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

<sub>Both the two most upvoted answers are wrong. It should have nothing to do with "store different/multiple languages". You can support Spanish characters like `ñ` and English, with just common `varchar` field and `Latin1_General_CI_AS` `COLLATION`, e.g.</sub>

**Short Version**
You should use `NVARCHAR`/`NCHAR` whenever the `ENCODING`, which is determined by `COLLATION` of the field, doesn't support the characters needed.
Also, depending on the SQL Server version, you can use specific `COLLATIONs`, like `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8` which is available since SQL Server 2019. Setting this collation on a `VARCHAR` field (or entire table/database), will use `UTF-8` `ENCODING` for storing and handling the data on that field, allowing fully support `UNICODE` characters, and hence any languages embraced by it.

**To FULLY UNDERSTAND:**
<sub>To fully understand what I'm about to explain, it's mandatory to have the concepts of `UNICODE`, `ENCODING` and `COLLATION` all extremely clear in your head.  If you don't, then first take a look below at my humble and simplified explanation on "What is UNICODE, ENCODING, COLLATION and UTF-8, and how they are related" section and supplied documentation links. Also, everything I say here is specific to `Microsoft SQL Server`, and how it stores and handles data in `char`/`nchar` and `varchar`/`nvarchar` fields.</sub>

Let's say we wanna store a peculiar text on our MSSQL Server database. It could be an Instagram comment as "I love stackoverflow! ". 
The plain English part would be perfectly supported even by ASCII, but since there are also an emoji, which is a character specified in the `UNICODE` standard, we need an `ENCODING` that supports this Unicode character.

MSSQL Server uses the `COLLATION` to determine what `ENCODING` is used on `char`/`nchar`/`varchar`/`nvarchar` fields. So, differently than a lot think, `COLLATION` **is not** only about sorting and comparing data, but also about `ENCODING`, and by consequence: **how our data will be stored!**

So, **HOW WE KNOW WHAT IS THE ENCODING USED BY OUR COLLATION?** With this:

```
SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY( 'Latin1_General_CI_AI' , 'CodePage' ) AS [CodePage]
--returns 1252
```

This simple SQL returns the `Windows Code Page` for a `COLLATION`. A `Windows Code Page` is nothing more than another mapping to `ENCODINGs`. For the `Latin1_General_CI_AI` `COLLATION` it returns the `Windows Code Page` code `1252` , that maps to `Windows-1252` `ENCODING`.
So, for a `varchar` column, with `Latin1_General_CI_AI` `COLLATION`, this field will handle its data using the `Windows-1252` `ENCODING`, and only correctly store characters supported by this encoding.

If we check the `Windows-1252 ENCODING` specification [Character List for Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), we will find out that this encoding won't support our emoji character. And if we still try it out:

[image: A text containing UNICODE characters, wrongfully being stored, due our collation and encoding on the varchar field]

**OK, SO HOW CAN WE SOLVE THIS??** Actually, it depends, and that is GOOD!

**`NCHAR`/`NVARCHAR`**

Before SQL Server 2019 all we had was `NCHAR` and `NVARCHAR` fields. Some say they are `UNICODE` fields. **THAT IS WRONG!**. Again, it depends on the field's `COLLATION` and also SQLServer Version.
Microsoft's ["nchar and nvarchar (Transact-SQL)" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) specifies perfectly:

> Starting with SQL Server 2012 (11.x), when a
> Supplementary Character (SC) enabled collation is used, these data
> types store the full range of Unicode character data and use the
> UTF-16 character encoding. If a non-SC collation is specified, then
> these data types store only the subset of character data supported by
> the UCS-2 character encoding.

In other words, if we use SQL Server older that 2012, like SQL Server 2008 R2 for example, the `ENCODING` for those fields will use `UCS-2 ENCODING` which support a subset of `UNICODE`. But if we use SQL Server 2012 or newer, and define a `COLLATION` that has `Supplementary Character` enabled, than with our field will use the `UTF-16` `ENCODING`, that fully supports `UNICODE`.

**BUT WHAIT, THERE IS MORE! WE CAN USE UTF-8 NOW!!**

**`CHAR`/`VARCHAR`**

Starting with SQL Server 2019, **WE CAN USE `CHAR`/`VARCHAR`** fields and still fully support `UNICODE` using `UTF-8` `ENCODING`!!!

From Microsoft's ["char and varchar (Transact-SQL)" documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

> Starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x), when a
> UTF-8 enabled collation is used, these data types store the full range
> of Unicode character data and use the UTF-8 character encoding. If a
> non-UTF-8 collation is specified, then these data types store only a
> subset of characters supported by the corresponding code page of that
> collation.

Again, in other words, if we use SQL Server older that 2019, like SQL Server 2008 R2 for example, we need to check the `ENCODING` using the method explained before. But if we use SQL Server 2019 or newer, and define a `COLLATION` like `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8`, then our field will use `UTF-8` `ENCODING` which is by far the most used and efficient encoding that supports all the `UNICODE` characters.

**Bonus Information:**

Regarding the OP's observation on *"I have seen that most of the European languages (German, Italian, English, ...) are fine in the same database in VARCHAR columns"*, I think it's nice to know why it is:

For the most common `COLLATIONs`, like the default ones as `Latin1_General_CI_AI` or `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` the `ENCODING` will be `Windows-1252` for `varchar` fields. If we take a look on it's [documentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), we can see that it supports:

> English, Irish, Italian, Norwegian, Portuguese, Spanish, Swedish. Plus
> also German, Finnish and French. And Dutch except the Ĳ character

But as I said before, it's not about language, it's about what characters do you expect to support/store, as shown in the emoji example, or some sentence like "The electric resistance of a lithium battery is 0.5Ω" where we have again plain English, and a Greek letter/character "omega" (which is the symbol for resistance in ohms), which won't be correctly handled by `Windows-1252` `ENCODING`.

**Conclusion:**

So, there it is! When use `char`/`nchar` and `varchar`/`nvarchar` depends on the characters that you want to support, and also the version of your SQL Server that will determines which `COLLATIONs` and hence the `ENCODINGs` you have available.

**What is UNICODE, ENCODING, COLLATION and UTF-8, and how they are related**
<sub>Note: all the explanations below are **simplifications**. Please, refer to the supplied documentation links to know all the details about those concepts.</sub>

- **`UNICODE`** - Is a standard, a convention, that aims to regulate all the characters in a unified and organized table. In this table, every character has an unique number. This number is commonly called character's `code point`.
  **UNICODE IS NOT AN ENCODING!**
- **`ENCODING`** - Is a mapping between a character and a byte/bytes sequence. So a encoding is used to "transform" a character to bytes and also the other way around, from bytes to a character. Among the most popular ones are `UTF-8`, `ISO-8859-1`, `Windows-1252` and `ASCII`. You can think of it as a "conversion table" (i really simplified here).
- **`COLLATION`** - That one is important. Even Microsoft's documentation doesn't let this clear as it should be. A Collation specifies how your data would be sorted, compared, **AND STORED!**. Yeah, I bet you was not expecting for that last one, right!? The collations on `SQL Server` determines too what would be the `ENCODING` used on that particular `char`/`nchar`/`varchar`/`nvarchar` field.
- **`ASCII ENCODING`** - Was one of the firsts encodings. It is both the character table (like an own tiny version of `UNICODE`) and its byte mappings. So it doesn't map a byte to `UNICODE`, but map a byte to its own character's table. Also, it always use only 7bits, and supported 128 different characters. It was enough to support all English letters upper and down cased, numbers, punctuation and some other limited number of characters. The problem with ASCII is that since it only used 7bits and almost every computer was 8bits at the time, there were another 128 possibilities of characters to be "explored", and everybody started to map this "available" bytes to its own table of characters, creating a lot of different `ENCODINGs`.
- **`UTF-8 ENCODING`** - This is another `ENCODING`, one of the most (if not the most) used `ENCODING` around. It uses variable byte width (one character can be from 1 to 6 bytes long, by specification) and fully supports all `UNICODE` characters.
- **`Windows-1252 ENCODING`** - Also one of the most used `ENCODING`, it's widely used on SQL Server. It's fixed-size, so every one character is always 1byte. It also supports a lot of accents, from various languages but doesn't support all existing, nor supports `UNICODE`. *That's why your `varchar` field with a common collation like `Latin1_General_CI_AS` supports `á`,`é`,`ñ` characters, even that it isn't using a supportive `UNICODE` `ENCODING`.*

Resources:
https://blog.greglow.com/2019/07/25/sql-think-that-varchar-characters-if-so-think-again/
https://medium.com/@apiltamang/unicode-utf-8-and-ascii-encodings-made-easy-5bfbe3a1c45a
https://www.johndcook.com/blog/2019/09/09/how-utf-8-works/
https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-what-is-encoding

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters
https://www.fileformat.info/info/charset/windows-1252/list.htm

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/windows-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/sql-server-collation-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support?view=sql-server-ver15#SQL-collations

[SQL Server default character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182164/sql-server-default-character-encoding)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_code_page

Answer (score 130):

The real reason you want to use NVARCHAR is when you have **different** languages in the same column, you need to address the columns in T-SQL without decoding, you want to be able to see the data "natively" in SSMS, or you want to standardize on Unicode.

If you treat the database as dumb storage, it is perfectly possible to store wide strings and different (even variable-length) encodings in VARCHAR (for instance UTF-8).  The problem comes when you are attempting to encode and decode, especially if the code page is different for different rows.  It also means that the SQL Server will not be able to deal with the data easily for purposes of querying within T-SQL on (potentially variably) encoded columns.

Using NVARCHAR avoids all this.

I would recommend NVARCHAR for any column which will have user-entered data in it which is relatively unconstrained.

I would recommend VARCHAR for any column which is a natural key (like a vehicle license plate, SSN, serial number, service tag, order number, airport callsign, etc) which is typically defined and constrained by a standard or legislation or convention.  Also VARCHAR for user-entered, and very constrained (like a phone number) or a code (ACTIVE/CLOSED, Y/N, M/F, M/S/D/W, etc).  There is absolutely no reason to use NVARCHAR for those.

So for a simple rule:

VARCHAR when guaranteed to be constrained
NVARCHAR otherwise

Comment: It should be noted that *"different languages"* doesn't just mean that different rows can contain values from different languages. It also means if default collation of the database (i.e. the server machine's locale) is different from the locale of any client computer. e.g. The server machine is set to `en-US`, but my PC is set to `fr-US`.

Comment: @IanBoyd In general, collation is going to be highly problematic when mixing languages in a column and returning items in multiple languages in a single set and using that collation for ordering.  Collation can also have an effect on characters being combined to be treated as one (Hungarian dz and ly): http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic19439-9-1.aspx http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207590/sql-server-case-collation-issue - nvarchar isn't going to solve that

Comment: A number of Asian nations (including China) uses logograms in their license plates, so unless you'll be 100% sure that your program absolutely will not and will never process this kind of data, you're better off using nvarchar for license plates. And yes, this includes stuff like traffic violator registration, parking garages and vehicle transport methods. It's entirely possible that someone from China takes a ferry or even drives to your country and stations their car in your garage.

Comment: This is not correct: `it is perfectly possible to store wide strings and different (even variable-length) encodings in VARCHAR (for instance UTF-8)`. You can't store characters that are not supported by the encoding of the column. If the column has a `Latin1_General_CI_AS` collation, it would have the `Windows-1252` enconding, hence you would not be able to store a emoji, a greek letter `Ω`, or the `ẃ` character for exemple. There is no correct mapping in the `Windows-1252` encoding for that bytes sequence. The `ẃ` would be a stored as `?`, and `Ω` would be converted to `O`.

Answer (score 12):

You should use NVARCHAR anytime you have to store multiple languages. I believe you have to use it for the Asian languages but don't quote me on it.

Here's the problem if you take Russian for example and store it in a varchar, you will be fine so long as you define the correct code page. But let's say your using a default english sql install, then the russian characters will not be handled correctly. If you were using NVARCHAR() they would be handled properly.

## Edit

Ok let me quote [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962.aspx#intlftrql2005_topic2) and maybee I was to specific but you don't want to store more then one code page in a varcar column, while you can you shouldn't

> When you deal with text data that is
>   stored in the char, varchar,
>   varchar(max), or text data type, the
>   most important limitation to consider
>   is that only information from a single
>   code page can be validated by the
>   system. (You can store data from
>   multiple code pages, but this is not
>   recommended.) The exact code page used
>   to validate and store the data depends
>   on the collation of the column. If a
>   column-level collation has not been
>   defined, the collation of the database
>   is used. To determine the code page
>   that is used for a given column, you
>   can use the COLLATIONPROPERTY
>   function, as shown in the following
>   code examples:

Here's some more:

> This example illustrates the fact that
>   many locales, such as Georgian and
>   Hindi, do not have code pages, as they
>   are Unicode-only collations. Those
>   collations are not appropriate for
>   columns that use the char, varchar, or
>   text data type

So Georgian or Hindi really need to be stored as nvarchar. Arabic is also a problem:

> Another problem you might encounter is
>   the inability to store data when not
>   all of the characters you wish to
>   support are contained in the code
>   page. In many cases, Windows considers
>   a particular code page to be a "best
>   fit" code page, which means there is
>   no guarantee that you can rely on the
>   code page to handle all text; it is
>   merely the best one available. An
>   example of this is the Arabic script:
>   it supports a wide array of languages,
>   including Baluchi, Berber, Farsi,
>   Kashmiri, Kazakh, Kirghiz, Pashto,
>   Sindhi, Uighur, Urdu, and more. All of
>   these languages have additional
>   characters beyond those in the Arabic
>   language as defined in Windows code
>   page 1256. If you attempt to store
>   these extra characters in a
>   non-Unicode column that has the Arabic
>   collation, the characters are
>   converted into question marks.

Something to keep in mind when you are using Unicode although you can store different languages in a single column you can only sort using a single collation. There are some languages that use latin characters but do not sort like other latin languages. Accents is a good example of this, I can't remeber the example but there was a eastern european language whose Y didn't sort like the English Y. Then there is the spanish ch which spanish users expet to be sorted after h.

All in all with all the issues you have to deal with when dealing with internalitionalization. It is my opinion that is easier to just use Unicode characters from the start, avoid the extra conversions and take the space hit. Hence my statement earlier.

Comment: >>You should use NVARCHAR anytime you have to store multiple languages
This is not true. German and Italian and English fit well in same table with VARCHAR columns. 
Please be more specific

Comment: See http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic19439-9-1.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207590/sql-server-case-collation-issue for examples with dz and ly in Hungarian.

Answer (score 5):

Greek would need UTF-8 on N column types: αβγ ;)

Answer (score 2):

Josh says:
"....Something to keep in mind when you are using Unicode although you can store different languages in a single column you can only sort using a single collation. There are some languages that use latin characters but do not sort like other latin languages. Accents is a good example of this, I can't remeber the example but there was a eastern european language whose Y didn't sort like the English Y. Then there is the spanish ch which spanish users expet to be sorted after h."

I'm a native Spanish Speaker and "ch" is not a letter but two "c" and "h" and the Spanish alphabet is like:
abcdefghijklmn ñ opqrstuvwxyz
We don't expect "ch" after "h" but "i"
The alphabet is the same as in English except for the ñ or in HTML "&ntilde ;"

Alex

Comment: Hi Alex, did you ever store different languages in 1 column? We had different columns for different languages in 1 table.

Comment: They are probably referencing Czech. We have "ch" between "h" and "i" and it is a separate letter of alphabet.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR;**
Unicode - (nchar, nvarchar, and ntext)
Non-unicode -  (char, varchar, and text).

[From MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms143726.aspx)

> Collations in SQL Server provide sorting rules, case, and accent
>   sensitivity properties for your data. Collations that are used with
>   character data types such as char and varchar dictate the code page
>   and corresponding characters that can be represented for that data
>   type.

Assuming you are using default SQL collation `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` then following script should print out all the symbols that you can fit in `VARCHAR` since it uses one byte to store one character (256 total) if you don't see it on the list printed - you need `NVARCHAR`.

```
declare @i int = 0;
while (@i < 256)
begin
print cast(@i as varchar(3)) + '  '+  char(@i)  collate SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS 
print cast(@i as varchar(3)) + '  '+ char(@i)  collate Japanese_90_CI_AS  
set @i = @i+1;
end
```

If you change collation to lets say japanese you will notice that all the weird European letters turned into normal and some symbols into `?` marks.

> Unicode is a standard for mapping code points to characters. Because
>   it is designed to cover all the characters of all the languages of the
>   world, there is no need for different code pages to handle different
>   sets of characters. If you store character data that reflects multiple
>   languages, always use Unicode data types (nchar, nvarchar, and ntext)
>   instead of the non-Unicode data types (char, varchar, and text).

Otherwise your sorting will go weird.

Comment: "Unicode - (nchar, nvarchar, and ntext). Non-unicode - (char, varchar, and text)." this is not correct. `nchar`/`nvarchar` uses different `encodings` in different version of SQL Server, like `UCS-2` which doesn't fully support `UNICODE`.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is facing this issue in Mysql there is no need to change varchar to nvarchar you can just change the collation of the column to utf8