# ADO.NET + Sql Server Varchar encoding problem

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, character-encoding, varchar

Put simply, I have a set of special characters in a Sql Server database varchar column, and I want to fetch it from a C# application.

Now the difficulty is: using Query Analyzer, I get the desired value of: "·°ï££".

However, through the client application, I end up with: "À░´úú".

It's a varchar column in a database with collation SQL_Latin1_General_CP850_CI_AI. In C#, I'm using default encoding.
I'm at a loss - any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You need the column type changed to NVARCHAR to support unicode.

see a previous [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612430/when-must-we-use-nvarchar-nchar-instead-of-varchar-char-in-sql-server)

Comment: But if I can get the correct value in QueryAnalyzer with the column being varchar, should't the client get the same value?