# SQL Server default character encoding

Tags: sql-server, character-encoding, collation

By default - what is the character encoding set for a database in Microsoft SQL Server?

How can I see the current character encoding in SQL Server?

Comment: Do you mean collation setting?

Comment: As I remember in `MSSQL` xml is stored in `UTF-16`, nchar's is stored in `UCS-2`

Comment: I'm not sure whether collation is the correct term, I mean for instance if it's using "utf-8" or "iso-8859-1" etc

Comment: @david, a SQL Server collation is more than a character set. It involves sort ordering and case sensitivity. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187582.aspx

Comment: @david, SQL Server does not implicity use utf-8. For 8-bit data, it uses a codepage that it determined by the collation in use. For 16-bit data, it uses UCS-2. Whether a particular column is 8-bit or 16-bit is determined by that column datatype, e.g., varchar or nvarchar.

Comment: Interesting that the second posted version of the same answer (with a misspelled function, even!) is the accepted answer.

Comment: @Johnny There is no encoding difference between UTF-16 and UCS-2. The only difference is if Surrogate Pairs of UCS-2 / BMP Code Points are recognized as Code Points themselves (i.e. Supplementary Characters).

Answer (score 58, accepted):

If you need to know the default collation for a newly created database use:

`SELECT SERVERPROPERTY('Collation')`

This is the server collation for the SQL Server instance that you are running.

Comment: the OP asked for character encoding, not collation.

Comment: @1010, collation determines encoding in SQL Server.

Comment: afaik sqlserver uses UC2 for the unicode datatypes, the collation value that you get with SERVERPROPERTY hints the codepage used in the non unicode datatypes, but you have to look it up. (for example Modern Spanish is Windows1252)

Comment: Does that mean that I cannot stick with the standard `varchar` even by setting the entire database to a Unicode encoding? I've only found non-Unicode looking collations. I'm thinking of how MySQL does it: You can specify the charset (meaning encoding) and the collation on the db, table, and column level and don't need such strange things like `nvarchar` and `N'Text'` with all its conversion issues.

Comment: @LonelyPixel, the short answer is no. But the answer is a bit more involved. see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143726.aspx and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9756769/what-is-the-point-of-collations-for-nvarchar-unicode-columns

Comment: @ygoe Correct, SQL Server does not allow for setting `VARCHAR` columns to a Unicode encoding like some other RDBMS's do. And, `NVARCHAR` (as well as `XML`) data only has a single encoding: UTF-16 Little Endian. The default handling, in terms of the built-in functions, of that UTF-16 data (i.e. when not using a collation ending in `_SC`) is to only correctly interpret the initial UCS-2 characters, which are a subset of the UTF-16 characters.

Comment: @ygoe (and others): starting in SQL Server 2019, UTF-8 is now an option for `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` columns, variables, and string literals. Please see my post for details on this new feature: "[Native UTF-8 Support in SQL Server 2019: Savior or False Prophet?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/09/28/native-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-savior-false-prophet-or-both/)"

Answer (score 63):

### Encodings

In most cases, SQL Server stores Unicode data (i.e. that which is found in the `XML` and `N`-prefixed types) in UCS-2 / UTF-16 (storage is the same, UTF-16 merely handles Supplementary Characters correctly). This is not configurable: there is no option to use <del>either UTF-8 or</del> UTF-32 <sup>(see **UPDATE** section at the bottom re: UTF-8 starting in SQL Server 2019)</sup>. Whether or not the built-in functions can properly handle Supplementary Characters, and whether or not those are sorted and compared properly, depends on the Collation being used. The older Collations — names starting with `SQL_` (e.g. `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`) *xor* no version number in the name (e.g. `Latin1_General_CI_AS`) — equate all Supplementary Characters with each other (due to having no sort weight). Starting in SQL Server 2005 they introduced the `90` series Collations (those with `_90_` in the name) that could at least do a binary comparison on Supplementary Characters so that you could differentiate between them, even if they didn't sort in the desired order. That also holds true for the `100` series Collations introduced in SQL Server 2008. SQL Server 2012 introduced Collations with names ending in `_SC` that not only sort Supplementary Characters properly, but also allow the built-in functions to interpret them as expected (i.e. treating the surrogate pair as a single entity). Starting in SQL Server 2017, all new Collations (the `140` series) [implicitly support Supplementary Characters](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2017/10/16/all-new-collations-in-sql-server-2017-implicitly-support-supplementary-characters/), hence there are no new Collations with names ending in `_SC`.

Starting in SQL Server 2019, UTF-8 became a supported encoding for `CHAR` and `VARCHAR` data (columns, variables, and literals), but not `TEXT` <sup>(see **UPDATE** section at the bottom re: UTF-8 starting in SQL Server 2019)</sup>.

Non-Unicode data (i.e. that which is found in the `CHAR`, `VARCHAR`, and `TEXT` types — but don't use `TEXT`, use `VARCHAR(MAX)` instead) uses an 8-bit encoding (Extended ASCII, DBCS, or EBCDIC). The specific character set / encoding is based on the Code Page, which in turn is based on the Collation of a column, or the Collation of the current database for literals and variables, or the Collation of the Instance for variable / cursor names and `GOTO` labels, or what is specified in a `COLLATE` clause if one is being used.

To see how locales match up to collations, check out:

- [Windows Collation Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188046.aspx)
- [SQL Server Collation Name](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180175.aspx)

To see the Code Page associated with a particular Collation (this is the character set and only affects `CHAR` / `VARCHAR` / `TEXT` data), run the following:

```sql
SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY( 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS' , 'CodePage' ) AS [CodePage];
```

To see the LCID (i.e. locale) associated with a particular Collation (this affects the sorting & comparison rules), run the following:

```sql
SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY( 'Latin1_General_100_CI_AS' , 'LCID' ) AS [LCID];
```

To view the list of available Collations, along with their associated LCIDs and Code Pages, run:

```sql
SELECT [name],
       COLLATIONPROPERTY( [name], 'LCID' ) AS [LCID],
       COLLATIONPROPERTY( [name], 'CodePage' ) AS [CodePage]
FROM sys.fn_helpcollations()
ORDER BY [name];
```

### Defaults

Before looking at the Server and Database default Collations, one should understand the relative importance of those defaults.

The Server (Instance, really) default Collation is used as the default for newly created Databases (including the system Databases: `master`, `model`, `msdb`, and `tempdb`). But this does not mean that any Database (other than the 4 system DBs) is using that Collation. The Database default Collation can be changed at any time (though there are dependencies that might prevent a Database from having it's Collation changed). The Server default Collation, however, is not so easy to change. For details on changing all collations, please see: [Changing the Collation of the Instance, the Databases, and All Columns in All User Databases: What Could Possibly Go Wrong?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/06/11/changing-the-collation-of-the-instance-and-all-columns-across-all-user-databases-what-could-possibly-go-wrong/)

The server/Instance Collation controls:

- local variable *names*
- `CURSOR` names
- `GOTO` labels
- Instance-level meta-data

The Database default Collation is used in three ways:

- as the default for newly created string columns. But this does not mean that any string column is using that Collation. The Collation of a column can be changed at any time. Here knowing the Database default is important as an indication of what the string columns are most likely set to.
- as the Collation for operations involving string literals, variables, and built-in functions that do not take string inputs but produces a string output (i.e. `IF (@InputParam = 'something')` ). Here knowing the Database default is definitely important as it governs how these operations will behave.
- Database-level meta-data

The column Collation is either specified in the `COLLATE` clause at the time of the `CREATE TABLE` or an `ALTER TABLE {table_name} ALTER COLUMN`, or if not specified, taken from the Database default.

Since there are several layers here where a Collation can be specified (Database default / columns / literals & variables), the resulting Collation is determined by [Collation Precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179886.aspx).

All of that being said, the following query shows the default / current settings for the OS, SQL Server Instance, and specified Database:

```sql
SELECT os_language_version,
       ---
       SERVERPROPERTY('LCID') AS 'Instance-LCID',
       SERVERPROPERTY('Collation') AS 'Instance-Collation',
       SERVERPROPERTY('ComparisonStyle') AS 'Instance-ComparisonStyle',
       SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrder') AS 'Instance-SqlSortOrder',
       SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrderName') AS 'Instance-SqlSortOrderName',
       SERVERPROPERTY('SqlCharSet') AS 'Instance-SqlCharSet',
       SERVERPROPERTY('SqlCharSetName') AS 'Instance-SqlCharSetName',
       ---
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'{database_name}', 'LCID') AS 'Database-LCID',
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'{database_name}', 'Collation') AS 'Database-Collation',
  DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'{database_name}', 'ComparisonStyle') AS 'Database-ComparisonStyle',
       DATABASEPROPERTYEX(N'{database_name}', 'SQLSortOrder') AS 'Database-SQLSortOrder'
FROM   sys.dm_os_windows_info;
```

### Installation Default

Another interpretation of "default" could mean what default Collation is selected for the *Instance-level* collation when installing. That varies based on the OS language, but the (horrible, horrible) default for systems using "US English" is `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`. In that case, the "default" encoding is Windows Code Page 1252 for `VARCHAR` data, and as always, UTF-16 for `NVARCHAR` data. You can find the list of OS language to default SQL Server collation here: [Collation and Unicode support: Server-level collations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/collations/collation-and-unicode-support#Server-level-collations). Keep in mind that these defaults can be overridden; this list is merely what the Instance will use if not overridden during install.

---

**UPDATE 2018-10-02**

SQL Server 2019 introduces native support for UTF-8 in `VARCHAR` / `CHAR` datatypes (not `TEXT`!). This is accomplished via a set of new collations, the names of which all end with `_UTF8`. This is an interesting capability that will definitely help some folks, but there are some "quirks" with it, especially when UTF-8 isn't being used for all columns *and* the Database's default Collation, so don't use it just because you have heard that UTF-8 is magically better. UTF-8 was designed *solely* for ASCII compatibility: to enable ASCII-only systems (i.e. UNIX back in the day) to support Unicode without changing any existing code or files. That it saves space for data using mostly (or only) US English characters (and some punctuation) is a side-effect. When not using mostly (or only) US English characters, data can be the same size as UTF-16, or even larger, depending on which characters are being used. And, in cases where space is being saved, performance might improve, but it might also get worse.

For a detailed analysis of this new feature, please see my post, "[Native UTF-8 Support in SQL Server 2019: Savior or False Prophet?](https://sqlquantumleap.com/2018/09/28/native-utf-8-support-in-sql-server-2019-savior-false-prophet-or-both/)".

Comment: And in addition to the defaults above, BULK INSERT, by default, interprets the incoming file as encoded in the system OEM. You need to specify the code page in your WITH parameters, as, e.g. if incoming text is ANSII: CODEPAGE = 'ACP'

Comment: This is not an answer....this is a BIBLE!! Thanks!

Answer (score 24):

The default character encoding for a SQL Server database is iso_1, which is ISO 8859-1. Note that the character encoding depends on the data type of a column. You can get an idea of what character encodings are used for the columns in a database as well as the collations using this SQL:

```
select data_type, character_set_catalog, character_set_schema, character_set_name, collation_catalog, collation_schema, collation_name, count(*) count
from information_schema.columns
group by data_type, character_set_catalog, character_set_schema, character_set_name, collation_catalog, collation_schema, collation_name;
```

If it's using the default, the character_set_name should be iso_1 for the char and varchar data types.  Since nchar and nvarchar store Unicode data in UCS-2 format, the character_set_name for those data types is UNICODE.

Comment: This is not strictly correct. the default character encoding depends on the OS language option at the time of SQL Server installation.

Comment: Rob: @ThomasMcLeod is correct re: the default encoding (via the default collation) being set at install time. I have a link to the mapping between OS locale and default collation in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32879066/577765). A much larger issue with this answer, however, is that SQL Server does _not_, in any way, support the ISO-8859-1 character set. It uses the very similar Windows Code Page 1252, which it erroneously labels as "iso_1". (I'll be generous and guess that perhaps originally, when it was still Sybase, it did use ISO-8859-1 and switched to CP 1252 when it split)

Answer (score 16):

`SELECT DATABASEPROPERTYEX('DBName', 'Collation') SQLCollation;`

Where DBName is your database name.

Comment: Encoding (as per OP's question) and collation are not synonymous.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is worthy of a separate answer: although internally unicode data is stored as UTF-16 in Sql Server this is the Little Endian flavour, so if you're calling the database from an external system, you probably need to specify UTF-16LE.

Answer (score 0):

You can see collation settings for each table like the following code:

```sql
SELECT t.name TableName, c.name ColumnName, collation_name  
FROM sys.columns c  
INNER JOIN sys.tables t on c.object_id = t.object_id where t.name = 'name of table';
```