# Cannot insert ♥ character in MySQL table

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert a ♥ into a MySQL table with PHP. It comes from an input field.

The table's charset is utf8_general_ci, and in PHP I use `mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` right after connection is made.

But the ♥ just becomes a '?' when inserted.

I have also tried inserting ♥ into the table from phpMyAdmin, but it returns this error:

```
Warning: #1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x99\xA5' for column 'subject' at row 1
```

The result is also '?' instead of ♥.

Any ideas on what causes this?

Comment: Try to follow [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781103/sql-server-set-character-set-not-collation

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is because of incompatible [character set and collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-column.html) defined on table's column.

Try [changing character set](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/charset-conversion.html) of your table or column to `UTF8`.

```
ALTER TABLE table_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE table_name MODIFY col VARCHAR(255) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Ohh! I just changed the charset of the table, not the columns... Changed the columns to utf8, and now everything works! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
ini_set('default_charset', 'utf-8');
```

in your php file and set the :

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

and chek in you data base for  **collation to utf8_general_ci**

Comment: default_charset and meta-tag wouldn't work, as I'm seeing the '?' in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: than try to set character encoding through ini_set()