# How to read Arabic characters from varchar datatype?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I have an old system that uses `varchar` datatype in its database to store Arabic names, now the names appear in the database like this:

```
  "ãíÓÇÁ ÇáãÈíÖíä"
```

Now I am building a new system using VB.NET, how can I read these names to appear in Arabic characters?

Also I need to point out here that the old system even it stores the data as I mentioned earlier it converts the characters in a correct format.

**How to display it properly in the new system and in the SQL Server Management Studio?**

Comment: yes that is correct. how do they read the characters right??

Comment: OK, I flagged it to be migrated to [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq), where you can get better answers.

Comment: Is the collation set correctly in the database for the relevant columns? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781103/sql-server-set-character-set-not-collation

Answer (score 1):

have you tried nvarchar? you may find some usefull information at the link below

[When must we use NVARCHAR/NCHAR instead of VARCHAR/CHAR in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612430/when-must-we-use-nvarchar-nchar-instead-of-varchar-char-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same Problem, and I solved it by two steps:

1.change the datatype of the column in DB into nvarchar

2.use the encoding to change the data into Arabic

I used the following function

```
     private string GetDataWithArabic(string srcData)
    {
        Encoding iso = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        Encoding unicode = Encoding.Default;
        byte[] unicodeBytes = iso.GetBytes(srcData);
        return unicode.GetString(unicodeBytes);
    }
```

but make sure you use this method once on DB data, because it will corrupt the data if used twice

Answer (score 0):

I think your answer is here: "storing and retrieving non english characters" http://aalamrangi.wordpress.com/2012/05/13/storing-and-retrieving-non-english-unicode-characters-hindi-czech-arabic-etc-in-sql-server/