# How to save unicode character in SQL database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I am trying to save ThinSpace (\u2009) to the database using ADO.NET classes, but instead I am getting "?" symbol in db in place of ThinSpace. String that I save to db in UTF8 format.

```
        var content = "This is a test";

        byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(content);
        content = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        content = content.Replace(' ', '\u2009');

        using (var con = new SqlConnection(connStr))
        {
            con.Open();

            using (var com = new SqlCommand("insert into Messages values ('" + content + "')", con))
            {
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
        }
```

Result in DB

[image]

Comment: have you tried `N'unicode text'` ?

Comment: just add big n(N) before the variable like so `"insert into Messages values (N'myValue')"`

Comment: Already check "N" . this does not help

Comment: Show us the new code that doesn't work

Comment: Is the MessageBody field an `NVARCHAR` or `VARCHAR`?

Comment: Don't build SQL queries through string concatenation. Use parameterized queries. If you're not familiar with what SQL injection is, become familiar with it.

Comment: @Daniel Mann I know what is SQL injection. This code written just like example for Stackoverflow. This is not production code. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ukrainian character change to question mark when insert to table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46196062/ukrainian-character-change-to-question-mark-when-insert-to-table)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you're trying to insert unicode into a `VARCHAR` column. The SQL below:

```
CREATE TABLE MessageBodies
(
     NVARCHARText NVARCHAR(255),
     VARCHARText VARCHAR(255)
);

DECLARE @Text AS NVARCHAR(MAX) = NCHAR(2009);

INSERT INTO UnicodeInserts
VALUES (@Text, @Text);

SELECT
    *
FROM 
    MessageBodies;
```

Returns:

[image]

We see that SQL Server Management Studio renders a `?` for an *unknown* character in a `VARCHAR` column. You'll need to convert your column to an `NVARCHAR` for the text to render as expected.

Answer (score 2):

may be this might help:

```
using (var com = new SqlCommand("insert into Messages values (@content)", con))
{
    var param = new SqlParameter("@content", SqlDbType.NVarChar);
    param.Value = content;
    com.Parameters.Add(param);
    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

your target column data type is needed to be NCHAR or NVARCHAR