# R programming Trouble importing unicode characters from SQL Server Database

Tags: r, sql-server, database, rodbc

I have trouble importing data from SQL Server with RODBC package. While importing, the process is smooth and imports quite nicely but there is a problem with unicode characters. They are changed to question marks(?). Have any of you ever come across  this problem? If yes please tell me how you've resolved it.

Comment: Do you mean in rstudio or in your output, see https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200532197-Character-Encoding

Comment: In rstudio, when you view dataset or subset anything from column which contains unicode I get question marks only, meaning it isn't reading the unicode characters

Answer (score 0):

The DBI package allows to set the encoding in the connexion descriptor to avoid special characters being transformed into question marks :

```
conn <- DBI::dbConnect(
                      odbc::odbc(),
                      Driver = "SQL Server",
                      ...,
                      encoding = "latin1"
                      )
```

In RODBC, you should also be able to set the DBMSencoding parameter

Comment: I connected with DBMSencoding set to 'latin1' but it still gives me question marks :/

Comment: maybe try utf-8?

Comment: I've tried utf-8 as well and utf-16 as well, still doesn't work

Comment: do you know what is the encoding of your SQL server?

Comment: Unfortunately no, is there a way to view what is there any other way to view the encoding of the server?

Comment: Have a look at :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5182164/sql-server-default-character-encoding