# Issues with accented characters when inserted to localdb

Tags: c#, encoding, localdb

I have a problem with my C# Winforms application. I have a form for entering data, which is converted into an object, then that is used to insert data into a localdb. My problem is with some Hungarian letters. We have a few characters with accents, like á, é, ő, ü, etc. My problem occurs at the point of insertion into the database. The SQL query (INSERT INTO) works just fine. However, if there is an 'Ő' or 'Ű' character (or lowercase 'ő' or 'ű') in the string which is inserted, that they are converted to their non-accented version (ő -> o; ű -> u). The other accented letters (like 'á') are working fine.

After some debugging, I can say for sure, that the characters are fine until reaching SQL query, so my class member (Customer.name) has them correctly - but they are inserted into the database in the wrong way. The strange thing is, if I enter the correct letter into the database directly (I mean, typing it into the database without an SQL query), then it stays there without an error, and is also displayed correctly in the app when using a select query.

I think my problem is some encoding-issue with the database, but I do not know how to change it, and what exactly can cause such issues with these 2 (or 4) characters.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the problem repro if you take your application out of the process (i.e., do the insert from SSMS)? Can you provide a minimal repro (simple table, one column, on string) and show the table DDL, the SQL collation, and how you are doing the insert from your code?

Comment: [SQL Server default character encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5182164/7444103) -- [What does 'COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS' do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5039211/7444103) etc.

Comment: Thank you for your help!
I was able to set collation to Hungarian, which solved my issue.