# georgian language support in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, collation, georgian

I hope there is some person from Georgia who might be able to help with my setup.

I have problem with Georgian database with SQL Server 2008R2. SQL Server is set to have default locale General Latin 1. it is running on Windows 7 which is installed with default English language. I am using this server to work with English, German, Slovak, Russian, Hebrew and Latvian databases without any problem.

now, when i try to create database using Georgian_Modern_Sort_CI_AS collation then database is created successfully, database structure is created but later when i try to use it it fails with error "The Collation specified by SQL Server is not supported."

I noticed that on MSDN page related to collations https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143508%28v=sql.105%29.aspx Georgian collation is marked with star. However I didn't found any description what this star means.

I checked regional settings in my Windows and I noticed that if I want to change system locale then Georgian is not available in the list. I can install Georgian as display language, but it made no change in available system locales anyway.

Any idea what should I do to be able to work with Georgian databases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ouch, not sure if this is good, but I found something in mssql 2005 that is saying there is no way for Georgian or Hindi and varchar :/

> The last example returns 0 (Unicode) as the code page for Hindi. This example illustrates the fact that many locales, such as Georgian and Hindi, do not have c?code pages, as they are Unicode-only collations. Those collations are not appropriate for columns that use the char, varchar, or text data type, and some collations have been deprecated. For a list of available collations and which collations are Unicode-only, see Collation Settings in Setup in SQL Server 2005 Books Online.

resources:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb330962(v=sql.90).aspx

[When must we use NVARCHAR/NCHAR instead of VARCHAR/CHAR in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/612430/when-must-we-use-nvarchar-nchar-instead-of-varchar-char-in-sql-server)

DO SOMEONE HAVE DIFFERENT WAY HOW TO AVOID USING NVARCHARs FOR GEORGIAN SCRIPT OR HINDI?