# Encoding varchar in sql server. Dynamic change encoding

Tags: sql-server, varchar

Which encoding is used for `varchar` in SQL server?

Can we dynamic change encoding of `varchar`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base64 encoding in SQL Server 2005 T-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082345/base64-encoding-in-sql-server-2005-t-sql)

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Late for the party, but the question remains very pertinent...</sub>

First question is **"Which encoding is used for varchar in SQL server?"**. That's a great question!

**Fast Answer:** Depends on the `COLLATION` *(see below)*. For the most common `COLLATIONs`, like the default ones as `Latin1_General_CI_AI` or `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS`, the `ENCODING` will be `Windows-1252`.
But since SQL Server 2019 we have `COLLATIONs` like `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8` which uses `UTF-8` `ENCODING`!

**Complete Answer:**

MSSQL Server uses the `COLLATION` to determine what `ENCODING` is used on `char`/`nchar`/`varchar`/`nvarchar` fields. So, differently than a lot think, `COLLATION` **is not** only about sorting and comparing data, but also about `ENCODING`, and by consequence: how our data will be stored.

So, **HOW WE KNOW WHAT IS THE ENCODING USED BY OUR COLLATION?** With this:

```
SELECT COLLATIONPROPERTY( 'Latin1_General_CI_AI' , 'CodePage' ) AS [CodePage]
--returns 1252
```

This simple SQL returns the `Windows Code Page` for a `COLLATION`. A `Windows Code Page` is nothing more than another mapping to `ENCODINGs`. For the `Latin1_General_CI_AI` `COLLATION` it returns the `Windows Code Page` code `1252` , that maps to `Windows-1252` `ENCODING`.
So, for a `varchar` column, with `Latin1_General_CI_AI` `COLLATION`, this field will handle its data using the `Windows-1252` `ENCODING`, and only correctly store characters supported by this encoding.

**UTF-8**

Starting with SQL Server 2019, **WE CAN USE `CHAR`/`VARCHAR`** fields and fully support `UNICODE` using `UTF-8` `ENCODING`!!!

From Microsoft's "char and varchar (Transact-SQL)" documentation:

> Starting with SQL Server 2019 (15.x), when a UTF-8 enabled collation
> is used, these data types store the full range of Unicode character
> data and use the UTF-8 character encoding. If a non-UTF-8 collation is
> specified, then these data types store only a subset of characters
> supported by the corresponding code page of that collation.

*https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/char-and-varchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15*

So if we use SQL Server older that 2019, like SQL Server 2008 R2 for example, we need to check the `ENCODING` using the method explained before. But if we use SQL Server 2019 or newer, and define a `COLLATION` like `Latin1_General_100_CI_AS_SC_UTF8`, then our field will use `UTF-8` `ENCODING` which is by far the most used and efficient encoding that supports all the `UNICODE` characters.

*You can see a more extended explanation covering `ENCODINGs` in the `char`/`nchar`/`varchar`/`nvarchar` fields, and other details on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63637996/3395460*

Second question is **"Can we dynamic change encoding of varchar?"**.

You can, although I don't see a good reason for that. With a ALTER TABLE, you can change a `COLLATION` of the entire table, or just a field, hence, changing the `ENCONDING` of it (actually you can even change the collation of entire database).

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTable 
ALTER COLUMN MyColumn VARCHAR(50) COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_SC_UTF8
```

There it is. But remember, the conversion of the data on those fields can cause **data loss**!

Answer (score 0):

Collation is defined at three different levels, each one overriding the previous.

First off you have the Server collation - that is the collation defined when you installed the instance and affects all subsequent objects unless redefined elsewhere
The second is the Database collation - this overrides the server collation and effects all the objects in the DB.
Last off each column in a table can have it's own collation.

```
Select  Convert (Varchar, ServerProperty('collation'));

Select  name, collation_name
From    sys.databases;

Select name, collation_name
From sys.columns
Where name = N'<ColumnName>' And Object_Id = Object_Id('<Table\ViewName>')
```

Changing the collation of a column isn't always easy as you have to locate all references to it first [This Script](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3221/how-to-change-the-collation-of-a-sql-server-column/) might help there.

Karasu CZ's right about one thing - an NVarChar resolves all these issues as NVarChar's are collation free. But that's not what you asked for!