# nvarchar change max size on the fly

Tags: sql

I've always been bothered by the need for max lengths on SQL string columns.  There is some data for which there is no true max length.  For example, let's say you have a field to store someone's first name, and you make it `NVARCHAR(50)`.  It's always possible (although highly unlikely) that someone has a name longer than 50 chars.

Would it be feasible to change the field's max length on the fly?  What I mean by this is, when you do an `INSERT/UPDATE`, you check if the person's name is longer than 50 chars, and `ALTER` the table if need be before you do the `INSERT/UPDATE`.  (Or perhaps, catch an exception and perform an `ALTER` if need be).

Would the `ALTER` be a slow operation if the table had a lot of data in it?

Let's say you alter the column to be `NVARCHAR(100)`.  Would a `SELECT` from this table be slower than if you'd made it `NVARCHAR(100)` from the beginning?

Comment: Altering your database schema on the fly is a terrible idea. Make the field as big as it reasonably should be and have your code responsible for validating inputs.

Comment: Choose good defaults. This thread question has some thoughtful answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/919871/how-big-do-you-make-your-nvarchar

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? Postgres? Another option is to define the columns as long as possible and then use a check constraint to ensure the business rules are kept. Changing the check constraint does not impose any physical change to the data

Answer (score 3):

From the use of `nvarchar()`, I am guessing that you are using SQL Server.

In SQL Server, I usually just make such names `varchar(255)` (or `nvarchar(255)`).  This is actually a weird anachronism of affinity to powers of 2 (255 = largest 8-bit unsigned value).  But it works well in practice.

You have at least two considerations in SQL Server.  First, the maximum "not-maximum" length of a string is 8000 data bytes, which is `varchar(8000)` or `nvarchar(4000)`.  These are reasonable maximum lengths as well.

The second consideration is the length of a key in an index.  The maximum length is 900 bytes.  If you have an index on the field, then you don't want the field longer than this.  If you have composite indexes, then 255 seems like a reasonable length.

The key point, however, is that changing the length of a field could have effects you are not thinking of, such as on the index.  You don't want to change the structure of a table lightly.  Instead, just make the field oversized to begin with, and forget about the problem entirely.

Comment: Note, that for some operations like hashing and sorting SQL Server estimates the avg. data size as columnlength/2... which is horrible. Goes wrong for nvarchar(4000).