# Difference between N'String' vs U'String' literals in Oracle

Tags: sql, string, oracle, literals, string-literals

What is the meaning and difference between these queries?

```
SELECT U'String' FROM dual;
```

and

```
SELECT N'String' FROM dual;
```

Comment: Please, check this: [Oracle: Programming with Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm)

Comment: It's weird how `N'` is listed in the SQL Language Reference but `U'` is not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

*In this answer i will try to provide informations from official resources*

## (1) The N'' text Literal

`N''` is used to convert a string to `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR2` datatype

**According to this Oracle documentation [Oracle - Literals](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements003.htm#i42617)**

> The syntax of text literals is as follows:
>
> [image]
>
> where `N` or `n` specifies the literal using the national character set (`NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR2` data).

**Also in this second article [Oracle - Datatypes](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements001.htm#i45685)**

The `N'String'` is used to convert a string to `NCHAR` datatype

From the article listed above:

> The following example compares the `translated_description` column of the `pm.product_descriptions` table with a **national character set string**:
>
> ```
> SELECT translated_description FROM product_descriptions
>   WHERE translated_name = N'LCD Monitor 11/PM';
> ```

---

## (2) The U'' Literal

`U''` is used to handle the SQL NCHAR String Literals in Oracle Call Interface (OCI)

**Based on this Oracle documentation [Programming with Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14225/ch7progrunicode.htm)**

> **The Oracle Call Interface** (OCI) is the lowest level API that the rest of the client-side database access products use. It provides a flexible way for C/C++ programs to access Unicode data stored in SQL `CHAR` and `NCHAR` datatypes. Using OCI, you can programmatically specify the character set (UTF-8, UTF-16, and others) for the data to be inserted or retrieved. It accesses the database through Oracle Net.

> OCI is the lowest-level API for accessing a database, so it offers the best possible performance.

> ### Handling SQL NCHAR String Literals in OCI
>
> You can switch it on by setting the environment variable `ORA_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE` to `TRUE`. You can also achieve this behavior programmatically by using the `OCI_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE_ON` and `OCI_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE_OFF` modes in `OCIEnvCreate()` and `OCIEnvNlsCreate()`. So, for example, `OCIEnvCreate(OCI_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE_ON)` turns on `NCHAR` literal replacement, while `OCIEnvCreate(OCI_NCHAR_LITERAL_REPLACE_OFF)` turns it off.
>
> [...] Note that, when the `NCHAR` literal replacement is turned on, `OCIStmtPrepare` and `OCIStmtPrepare2` **will transform `N'` literals with `U'` literals in the SQL text and store the resulting SQL text in the statement handle**. Thus, if the application uses `OCI_ATTR_STATEMENT` to retrieve the SQL text from the `OCI` statement handle, **the SQL text will return `U'` instead of `N'` as specified in the original text**.

---

## (3) Answer for your question

From datatypes perspective, there is not difference between both queries provided

Comment: Does it mean that `U'` is just C/C++ semantics rather than SQL/PLSQL?

Comment: Based on the documentation, it looks like that is true. The weird thing is that there is no examples or additional infos provided.

Answer (score 9):

- `N'string'` just returns the `string` as `NCHAR` type.
- `U'string'` returns also `NCHAR` type, however it does additional processing to the `string`: it replaces `\\` with `\` and `\xxxx` with Unicode code point `U+xxxx`, where `xxxx` are 4 hexadecimal digits. This is similar to `UNISTR('string')`, the difference is that the latter returns `NVARCHAR2`.

`U'` literals are useful when you want to have a Unicode string independent from encoding and NLS settings.

Example:

```
select n'\€', u'\\\20ac', n'\\\20ac' from dual;

N'\€' U'\\\20AC' N'\\\20AC'
----- ---------- ----------
\€    \€         \\\20ac
```

Answer (score 5):

when using `N'` we denote that given datatype is `NCHAR` or `NVARCHAR`.

`U'` is used to denote unicode

Comment: but nvarchar stores [unicode also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7854165/unicode-varchar-and-nvarchar)  can you explain more about the difference ?

Answer (score 0):

The documented `N''` literals are the same as standard character literals (`''`) except that their data type is NVARCHAR2 and not VARCHAR2. It is important to note that the characters in these literals, together with the entire SQL statement, are converted from the client character set to the database character set when transmitted to the server. All characters from the literals that are not supported by the database character set are lost.

The data type of the undocumented `U''` literals is also NVARCHAR2. The content of a `U''` literal is interpreted like the input to the SQL `UNISTR` function. That is, each character sequence `\xxxx`, where each `x` is one hex digit, is interpreted as a UTF-16 code point U+xxxx. I am not sure why the `U''` literals are undocumented. I can only guess. They are used internally by the NCHAR literal replacement feature, which, when enable on a client, automatically translates `N''` literals to `U''` literals. This prevents the mentioned data loss due to character set conversion and enables literal Unicode data to be provided for NVARCHAR2 columns even if the database character set is not Unicode.

The two queries in this thread's question are generally **not** equivalent because the literal text would be interpreted differently. However, if no backslash is present in the literals, no difference can be observed.