# what could be the datatype for the column having weblinks

Tags: sql, sql-server

One curious question. if i have a table with column with weblinks then what could be the datatype nvarchar or varchar. and what could be the size of that datatype?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url for a partial answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say `varchar(1000)` would be enough (unless you're going to store some Amazon URLs, of course) :). You don't need nvarchar because national URLs are experimental and are eventually converted to Latin with special characters.

> Typically Web servers set fairly generous limits on length for genuine URLs e.g. up to 2048 or 4096 characters.

So, if you want to be safe and still don't want to use `varchar(max)`, you can use `varchar(2048)` and `varchar(4096)`, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

In general, use nvarchar.
[What are the main performance differences between varchar and nvarchar SQL Server data types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366/varchar-vs-nvarchar-performance)

RFC2616 says there's no maximum length of a URL, but 2000 is probably safe.
[What is the maximum length of a URL in different browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-an-url)

Answer (score 1):

You should use nvarchar since chinese national characters were allowed in URL names and varchar can't handle those. Maximum URL size is 2083 characters (at least in IE), but you don't see those quite often. If you want to be completely sure that you can handle all URLs you shuold use `nvarchar(2083)`.

Comment: Shouldn't this be NVARCHAR(4166), given this remark in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/nchar-and-nvarchar-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#remarks) ?

Answer (score 0):

For data with embedded URLs, you can use either varchar or nvarchar.  The only difference between nvarchar and varchar is nvarchar is a varchar that natively supports unicode data.  Also, the storage space is larger: varchar is 8-bit, while unicode is 16-bit, so double the space.

Comment: One more note...unless you have non-english symbols in your URL (I'm not even sure that's possible, is it? I'm thinking it is not!), then varchar is the best choice.

Comment: Actualy, a while ago, Chinese characters could come inside URL

Answer (score 0):

A future-proof solution would be `nvarchar`, since recent movements toward full unicode domain names are noticable, e.g. [Russia Begins Registering Domains in Cyrillic](http://globalvoicesonline.org/2009/11/25/russia-begins-registering-domains-in-cyrillic/).

Answer (score 0):

URLs are subject to [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt):

> URLs are written only with the graphic
>   printable characters of the
>   US-ASCII coded character set. The
>   octets 80-FF hexadecimal are not
>   used in US-ASCII, and the octets 00-1F
>   and 7F hexadecimal represent
>   control characters; these must be
>   encoded

This would place all 'weblinks' safely in the VARCHAR camp. With SQL Server 2008 R2 though you need not to worry anymore, since [Unicode Compression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee240835.aspx) is available (on Enterprise and DataCenter Editions).